# Chamada de Método com parâmetros de uma Matriz

Tags: c, array, parâmetros

Sempre criei métodos de vetores usando:

```
void exemplo(int vetor[], int qtd){  
// Código...  
// ...  
}
```

E nunca tive problemas, porém estou tentando o mesmo com matrizes e recebo um erro

```
void exemplo(int matriz[][], int lin, int col){  
// Código...  
// ...  
}
```

O erro é:

> array type has incomplete element type

Segue uma imagem com o código

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Qual é o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em C [*arrays* não existem de verdade. No fundo eles são ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

Quando vai acessar um elemento `matriz[i]` na verdade está fazendo `*(matriz + i)`.

Em um *array* multidimensional `matriz[i][j]` está fazendo `*(matriz + i * dimensao + j)`. Qual é o valor de `dimensao` aí? Não tem como saber na forma como está usando. A multiplicação é necessária para obter o deslocamento. Uma dimensão é um agrupamento de elementos. Para acessá-los precisa saber quantos elementos tem em uma das dimensões. A outra não é necessário saber.

Se mudar o parâmetro para `int matriz[][3]` aí você estará fazendo `*(matriz + i * 3 + j)`. Você pode especificar o tamanho das duas dimensões se quiser: `int matriz[3][3]`.

Um exemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print(int matriz[][3], int lin, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) printf("%d, ", matriz[i][j]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[3][3] = {{0}};
    print(a, 3, 3);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/qyrT53). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cjkjsibx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/MatrixStack.c).

Uma solução é usar ponteiro ao invés de *array*. Aí você controla o acesso aos elementos na mão:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void print(int *matriz, int lin, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) printf("%d, ", *(matriz + i * col + j));
    }
}

int main() {
    int * a = malloc(9 * sizeof(int));
    print(a, 3, 3);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/vCJ0Rf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fnechogg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/MatrixHeap.c).

Comment: Acho, que entendi. Vou testar aqui antes da aula, mas eu gostaria mesmo de acessar uma linha e coluna da matriz usando ponteiro, por exemplo quero acessar matriz[4][2]. Como eu faria isso usando ponteiros? Não sei se vai conseguir entender o que quero dizer, mas obrigado!

Comment: Do jeito que eu mostrei na resposta.

Comment: Ah ok. Obrigado pela ajuda. Tenha um bom dia

Comment: Em C existem _arrays_ sim: `char *p; char a[32]; sizeof(p) != sizeof(a);` É verdade dizer que _arrays decaem_ para ponteiros.