# Arrays são ponteiros?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, tipagem

No fim das contas, em C, um array `a[]` se torna um ponteiro `*a`? Se não, o que são arrays? Quais as diferenças entre eles? Como os arrays funcionam internamente?

Comment: Boa pergunta, assim poderá ter algo canônico para usar em outras respostas que não cabem ficar explicando em detalhes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Primeiro, entenda que muitas vezes fazemos simplificações para dar entendimento para quem ainda não domina o assunto. Conforme a pessoa que é muito leiga vai evoluindo ela pode se atentar aos detalhes. Não vou passar todos aqui mas vou um pouco além da simplificação normalmente feita em respostas dadas para quem está aprendendo e ainda não consegue conversar no mesmo nível de quem já aprendeu tudo da linguagem.

## Introdução

***Arrays* não são ponteiros**. Na [resposta do pmg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91319/101) em outra pergunta tem até um [*link* onde mostra isto](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html). Formalmente são tipos diferentes. Em alguns casos é possível usar um quando se espera outro. Há uma conversão automática, mas não em todos. Há diferença semântica, além da óbvia diferença na sintaxe para cada um.

> Um *array* é uma única e previamente alocada porção de memória de elementos contínuos (todos de mesmo tipo), fixa em tamanho e em localização.

> Um ponteiro é uma referência para qualquer dado (de um tipo específico) em qualquer lugar.

Internamente eles funcionam como se fossem ponteiros. O computador não entende *arrays*. Esta é uma definição existente em linguagens de mais alto nível. É necessário um mecanismo de mais baixo nível para acessar os dados da memória. Este mecanismo é o ponteiro. Mas a definição formal dos termos e do funcionamento específico na linguagem C indica uma diferença entre eles.

O *array* pode ter a informação do seu tamanho conhecida pelo compilador. Neste caso ele obviamente não pode ter seu tamanho alterado. O ponteiro não tem tamanho definido. Existem *arrays* sem tamanho definido em tempo de compilação que se comportam mais próximo do ponteiro.

O *array* em si não pode ter seu tamanho alterado, mas, como ele pode ser acessado como um ponteiro, nada impede que se adicione informações no final dele (ainda que não seja simples fazer certo e nem seguro fazer isto, de fato provavelmente corromperá a memória) ou se acesse partes da memória além dele, como se fosse parte dele. O código deve cuidar disto.

A localização do *array* também não pode ser alterada, por definição. Se precisa trocar de local, no fundo estará criando outro *array*. O ponteiro pode ser trocado e apontar para outra localização, conforme a figura abaixo. Evidentemente que estará apontando para outro objeto, mesmo que tenha o mesmo conteúdo.

[image: Diferença array e ponteiro]

Um *array* [tem seu valor no mesmo local de armazenamento da variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Um ponteiro indica onde terá o valor de uma **possível** sequência de valores, ele aponta para o primeiro elemento. Mesmo o compilador sabendo o tamanho do *array* ele não ajuda a verificar se o acesso está sendo feito fora da faixa dele, o programador é responsável por tratar isto. O compilador impede um *array* de zero elementos, afinal ele não pode apontar para nada, ele tem que apontar para pelo menos o elemento 0. Se vai ter um valor útil lá é outro problema.

O tamanho de um *array* é o tamanho da alocação dele. O tamanho de um ponteiro é o tamanho do seu tipo. Para saber a quantidade de elementos de um *array* devemos fazer uma conta dividindo o tamanho do *array* pelo tamanho do tipo dele.

## Eles são intercambiáveis?

A questão é que para acessar um *array* ou um elemento específico dele é possível usar um ponteiro. Afinal o *array* está em algum lugar da memória e algum lugar da memória sempre pode ser acessado por um ponteiro. Não vou entrar nos detalhes de memória virtual e proteção de acesso, não vem ao caso agora.

Então a forma de acesso é intercambiável. De fato quando você faz `array[index]` está fazendo `*(array + index)` (lembrando que o valor de `index` é multiplicado pelo `sizeof` do tipo do *array*). Por isso há casos onde ocorre o decaimento de *array* para ponteiro. Obviamente é possível acessar um trecho da memória cuja localização é conhecida como se fosse um *array*, mesmo não sendo.

Por isso `array[index]` é o mesmo que `index[array]`, apesar de ser esquisito escrever assim. A ordem da soma não altera o resultado.

Há vários casos onde você tentar usar um no lugar de outro dá erro. Não é capricho do compilador, ele realmente terá problemas em executar a operação corretamente. Quando você usa uma referência para um *array*, o ponteiro pode ser usado no lugar.

Não há diferença/vantagem em usar `char array[]` (note que não há tamanho definido) ou `char *array` a não ser que a primeira indica com clareza que se trata de um *array*. É uma informação que serve ao programador.

Note que se você passar um *array* para uma função, a passagem será feita como se fosse uma referência. Porque no fundo é passado um ponteiro. Então a passagem é por valor, mas o valor é um ponteiro para o local onde está o *array* e não o *array* em si. Isto é uma das coisas que gera a confusão entre *array* e ponteiro. Isto ocorre mesmo quando se usa a sintaxe de *array* (`[]`), afinal elas são idênticas, mas no fundo está usando um ponteiro.

```
char array[] = "Hello world";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Basic.c).

`"Hello world"` é um *array* de tamanho 12 ([sabe porque é 12 e não 11, né?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155932/101)). Ele será alocado na memória (provavelmente uma área estática da memória e a variável `array` apontará para o endereço de sua localização. Entendeu por que falamos informalmente que o *array* é um ponteiro? Ele não é do tipo `pointer`, ele apenas aponta para algo.

## *Array* não existe?

Faltam facilidades na linguagem para manipular *arrays*. Tudo funciona como se fossem ponteiros, você tem que cuidar de tudo. Daí falamos informalmente que no fundo *array* não existe em C. Assim como *string* também não existe. Ainda que exista o tipo *array*, a linguagem não o trata de forma especial. Lembrando que *string* é apenas uma sequência de `char`. Elas podem ser alocadas em um *array* ou ponteiro. E obviamente pode ser intercambiado em algumas situações.

## Conclusão

Tecnicamente são tipos diferentes com mecanismos internos que funcionam da mesma forma e em algumas situações podem ser intercambiados.

Entenda que o ponteiro é muito mais flexível e um mecanismo mais genérico.

Os detalhes podem ser obtidos no *link* no início da resposta.

Answer (score 14):

Um array está associado com um espaço de memória capaz de suportar `N` elementos do tipo base do array.

Um ponteiro está associado com um espaço de memória capaz de apontar para outro espaço de memória.

A grande diferença entre ponteiro e array pode ser vista no resultado de `sizeof`

```
int value = 0;
int *ptr = &value;
int array[42] = {0};

printf("sizeof ptr = %d\n" (int)sizeof ptr);
printf("sizeof arr = %d\n" (int)sizeof arr);
```

O problema com a gestão de arrays e ponteiros prende-se com o facto que em muito dos usos feitos com arrays estes são convertidos (internamente pelo compilador) num ponteiro para o seu primeiro elemento (no caso de `sizeof` esta conversão não é aplicada), perdendo-se com esta conversão a informação de quantos elementos compõem o array.

Com o mesmo motivo, outro problema é a passagem de parametros entre funções quando estas incluem um (ou mais) array. O array é convertido para um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento e é este ponteiro que é passado (sem informação sobre o tamanho do array).

Outra razão para confundir os dois elementos da linguagem é que um ponteiro pode ser usado com a mesma sintaxe dum array.

```
int array[42] = {42};
int *ptr = a;
```

No código acima a variável array tem espaço para 42 valores de tipo `int`. A variável `ptr` aponta para o primeiro desses valores (para `a[0]`);

Para meter um valor especifico em, por exemplo `a[10]` podes usar o array ou o ponteiro com sintaxe igual

```
a[10] = 1000;
p[10] = 1000;
```

embora a "filosofia" base seja diferente (acesso directo versus acesso relativo).

---

*Imagina um array como um comboio e um ponteiro como uma pessoa a apontar para a primeira carruagem.*

Comment: surgiu-me a seguinte [dúvida](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91365/766) com esta tua resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Sendo curto e grosso... Sim, um vetor é um ponteiro, embora o contrário não seja sempre verdade.

Primeiro vamos às definições:

- **Um ponteiro** guarda um endereço de memória. Em uma arquitetura de 32 bits, um endereço tem 32 bits e corresponde ao tipo int. Isso tem um efeito muito legal: se você tiver um ponteiro qualquer e o incrementar, ele agora aponta para o próximo espaço da memória.
- **Vetores** são açúcar sintático para se executar duas tarefas: reservar um espaço da memória para guardar informações, e acessar essas informações com uma sintaxe mais simples.

Logo, note que os dois seguintes códigos alcançam o mesmo objetivo:

```
int vetor[10] = { 0 };
// Em C, isso gera um array com dez elementos de valor zero

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    vetor[i] = i;
    printf("%d", vetor[i]);
}
```

Nesse caso, será impresso: **0123456789** e o vetor conterá, na ordem, **0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9**.

Agora com ponteiros:

```
int *ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof *ptr);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    *(ptr + 1) = i;
    printf("%d", *(ptr + i));
}
```

O resultado impresso será o mesmo, e teremos na memória dez inteiros em posições consecutivas, na seguinte ordem: **0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9**.

Se você reparou bem, viu que tanto um código quanto o outro fizeram exatamente a mesma coisa. Mas o primeiro é mais simples e mais familiar para quem já trabalhou com outras linguagens de nível mais alto, como Java, C# ou Javascript (embora o vetor seja algo um tanto diferente nessa última).

Como são a mesma coisa, você pode misturar as duas formas impunemente :D Veja:

```
int *ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof *ptr);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ptr[i] = i;
    printf("%d", *(ptr + i));
}
```

E

```
int vetor[10] = { 0 };
int *ptr = &vetor[0];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    vetor[i] = i;
    printf("%d", *(ptr + i));
}
```

Espero ter respondido na prática a pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando as respostas dos companheiros acima. Um array como propriamente dito, é uma "variedade" de elementos do mesmo tipo dentro de um espaço determinado na memória. Linguagens de alto nível abstraem esse espaço com "index's".

A partir de um index referenciado à uma posição que, consecutivamente aponta para um endereço, é possível acessar, ler ou inserir dados sobre a posição indicada:

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 8
using namespace std;

int main() {
     int numeros[SIZE]; 
     numeros[0] = 1; // inserindo dados num array a partir de um index
     cout << numeros[0]; // lendo dados de um array a partir do index desejado
}
```

O index é uma forma simples de acessar um valor de um array. Ponteiros fazem este trabalho de forma complexa, eis um exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 8
using namespace std;

int numeros[SIZE]; // não se esqueça que todo array, de qualquer tipo inicia com posição 0

void AtribuirValor(); // protótipo da função

int main()
{
    AtribuirValor();
    int *ptr = numeros; // ponteiro para um array de 8 posições criado na stack referenciando ao array numeros

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "index: " << i << ", endereco: " << &ptr[i] << ", valor:" << ptr[i] << endl; // acessando os valores, index's e endereços do array numeros a partir de um ponteiro para inteiros 
    }

    cout << "\nComprovando... \n\n";

    for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) 
    {
        cout << "index: " << c << ", endereco: " << &numeros[c] << ", valor: " << numeros[c] << endl; // acessando os valores, index's e endereços do array numeros
    }
}

void AtribuirValor()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) 
    {
        numeros[j] = 10+j; // atribuindo valores para dentro do array 
    }
}


/*
OUTPUT: 
index: 0, endereco: 0x408020, valor:10
index: 1, endereco: 0x408024, valor:11
index: 2, endereco: 0x408028, valor:12
index: 3, endereco: 0x40802c, valor:13
index: 4, endereco: 0x408030, valor:14
index: 5, endereco: 0x408034, valor:15
index: 6, endereco: 0x408038, valor:16
index: 7, endereco: 0x40803c, valor:17 

Comprovando...

index: 0, endereco: 0x408020, valor: 10
index: 1, endereco: 0x408024, valor: 11
index: 2, endereco: 0x408028, valor: 12
index: 3, endereco: 0x40802c, valor: 13
index: 4, endereco: 0x408030, valor: 14
index: 5, endereco: 0x408034, valor: 15
index: 6, endereco: 0x408038, valor: 16
index: 7, endereco: 0x40803c, valor: 17
*/
```

Para os interessados, aqui está o disassemble da função main para arquitetura x64 - Windows 10:

```
   Dump of assembler code for function main:

   0x00401410 <+0>:     lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   0x00401414 <+4>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x00401417 <+7>:     pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   0x0040141a <+10>:    push   %ebp
   0x0040141b <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x0040141d <+13>:    push   %ecx
=> 0x0040141e <+14>:    sub    $0x24,%esp
   0x00401421 <+17>:    call   0x401bc0 <__main>
   0x00401426 <+22>:    call   0x4015a3 <_Z13AtribuirValorv>
   0x0040142b <+27>:    movl   $0x408020,-0x14(%ebp)
   0x00401432 <+34>:    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x00401439 <+41>:    cmpl   $0x7,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x0040143d <+45>:    jg     0x4014df <_fu0___ZSt4cout+145>
   0x00401443 <+51>:    movl   $0x406045,0x4(%esp)
   0x0040144b <+59>:    movl   $0x6ff44aa0,(%esp)
```

Answer (score -3):

arrays e ponteiros são coisas completamente diferentes . o pulo do gato é que quando o compilador precisa acessar um elemento do array  o compilador trata o array multidimensional como se fosse um  ponteiro. um ponteiro constante,ou seja um ponteiro cujo conteúdo  ,que é um endereço de memoria, não muda. este ponteiro aponta para uma região de memória.esta discussão não é para iniciantes, visto que é como o compilador trata um array por debaixo das curtinas. quando precisa trabalhar com um array , o compilador trata o array  com se fosse um ponteiro. o que acontece quando um compilador precisa acessar um array!  como se controe um array ? usando um ponteiro constante.

**Como funciona subscript num array multidimensional  na linguagem c ou como eu imagino que funcione um array multidimensional em *gcc* ou a estranha conexão entre array, ponteiro,  operador derreferencia e operador subscript.**

```
                       1 4 5                               
int meu_array[2][3]=   
                       3 7 8
```

Um array  tem o identificador `meu_array` e 2 dimensões com 6 elementos int .o identificador `meu_array` é tratado pelo compilador de duas maneiras:

primeira maneira. é tratado como se fosse um array de 2 dimensões e 6 elementos Exemplo:
`sizeof (meu_array);`

segunda maneira . o identificador `meu_array`  é tratado como   um  ponteiro que aponta para um  um  array  unidimensional de 3 elementos *int {1,4,5}*. este ponteiro tem um offset de 3 elementos  int  se for incrementado este ponteiro apontara para um novo array unidimensional de 3 elementos int o novo array  apontado  é *{3,7,8}*.

Um array multidimensional com n dimensões é tratado pelo compilador como se fosse  um ponteiro que aponta para um array dimensional com n-1 dimensões.

Isso mesmo é descartada   uma dimensão, perdesse uma informação nesse processo.este processo se chama decaimento  do array para um ponteiro (array decay).

Exemplos:

- `int  array1[4][5][6]`  o compilador interpreta array1 como
  se ele fosse um ponteiro dado pela seguinte expressão int (*ponteiro1)[5][6] .
- `int  array2 [2][3]`  o compilador  interpreta array2 como
  se ele fosse um ponteiro dado pela seguinte expressão int (*ponteiro2)[3] .
- `Float array3[6]` o compilador interpreta array3 como
  se ele fosse um ponteiro dado pela seguinte expressão float (*ponteiro3).

> Note pegando o caso de array1. Este é um array multidimensional de 4x5x6=120 elementos int,  mas  ponteiro1 aponta para um array multidimensional de 5x6=30 elementos int.

> Note pegando o caso de array2. Este é um array multidimensional de 2x3=6 elementos int ,mas  ponteiro2 aponta para um array multidimensional de 3 elementos int.

> Note pegando o caso de array3. Este é um array unidimensional  de 6 elementos mas o
> ponteiro3 aponta para um  elemento float.

> Note os offset. Ponteiro1 tem um offset de 5*6=30 int. Ponteiro2  tem um offset de 3 int .  Ponteiro3  tem um offset de 1 float.

Passando um array multidimensional como argumento de uma função

dado: `float array[2][3]` a declaração `void função_recebe_array(float array_parametro[2][3])`
é equivalente `void função_recebe_array( float (*ponteiro_parametro)[3])`  por isso devesse passar o valor da dimensão:
`void função_recebe_array( int linhas ,float (*ponteiro_parametro)[3])`

O que significa direferenciar um ponteiro que aponta para um array ?

O resultado de dereferenciar um ponteiro que aponta para um int é um valor int . No caso de um ponteiro que aponta para um array o resultado é um  array . Mas como esse  array é   um ponteiro  . Na pratica dereferenciar um ponteiro que aponta para  um array tem como resultado um  ponteiro que aponta para um novo array com n-1 dimensão.

Operador subscript e operador dereferencia

quando se escreve ,`array[i][j][k]`  o compilador interpreta como `*(*(*( array+i)+j)+k)`. Voce conseque adivinhar o resultado da expressão `array[0][0][0]` ? É o primeiro valor do array quando você usa subscript você esta usando de referencia de ponteiro que aponta para um array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
int matriz_2x3x4[2][3][4]={7,4,3,2,115,100,20,30,50,60,70,80,90,93,95,83,55,52,36,27,25,21,20,5};

printf("\no endereço de matriz_2x3x4 é %p \n",&matriz_2x3x4[0][0][0]);
printf("\no valor  de matriz_2x3x4[1][2][3] é %i \n",matriz_2x3x4[1][2][3]);
printf("\no valor  de matriz_2x3x4[1][2][3]  é %i \n",*(*(*(matriz_2x3x4+1)+2)+3));

int  (*ponteiro_matrix_3x4)[3][4]=matriz_2x3x4;
printf("\n o ponteiro_matrix_3x4 aponta para   %p \n",matriz_2x3x4);
int  (*ponteiro_array_4)[4]=*(matriz_2x3x4+1);
printf("\n o ponteiro_array_4 aponta para   %p \n",ponteiro_array_4);
printf("\n a segunda matrix_3x4 aponta para   %p \n",&(matriz_2x3x4[1][0][0]));
int  (*ponteiro_int)=*(ponteiro_array_4+2);
printf("\n o ponteiro_array_4 aponta para o endereço  %p \n",ponteiro_array_4);
printf("\n o valor 90 esta no endereço   %p \n",&(matriz_2x3x4[1][0][0]) );

printf("\n o ponteiro_array_4 +2 aponta para o endereço  %p \n",ponteiro_array_4+2);
printf("\n o valor 25 esta no endereço   %p \n",&(matriz_2x3x4[1][2][0]) );

                 
int  elemento_1_2_3_da_matriz=*(ponteiro_int+3);
printf("\n o elemento matriz_2x3x4[1][2][3] e   %i \n",elemento_1_2_3_da_matriz);

return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

bibliografia :
https://riptutorial.com/c/example/13402/misunderstanding-array-decay

Comment: Você confundiu a abstração com a implementação do array e juntou numa coisa só. Array é só um ponteiro para um espaço reservado de memória. Como se desloca dentro desse espaço reservado de memória é abstração.

Comment: Sua resposta está sem sentido

Answer (score -4):

Se você tem um array com 'n' posições, ele é um ponteiro quando se colocado apenas sua nomenclatura, isto é, você não indexa ele, deste modo:

```
int array[10];
array[0... 9]; <-- Quando você colocar uma posição específica ele se torna uma estância de uma variável, porém se colocado da forma abaixo:   

array;  <-- este se trata de um ponteiro que aponta para estas 10 posições na memória.
```