# Como uma variável é apontada para um ponteiro?

Tags: c, array, variáveis, ponteiro, memória

Lendo [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91362/766) sobre ponteiros e *arrays* em C, há o exemplo abaixo onde a variável `ptr` aponta para o o primeiro elemento desse *array*.

```
int array[42] = {42};
int *ptr = a;
```

Como esse ponteiro identifica o primeiro elemento do *array* apenas atribuindo o valor `a`?

Comment: Não tem nada errado com seu código?

Comment: Não sei, o código não é meu. Retirei da resposta da questão como disse, porém não entendi o funcionamento dela.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que seu código é

```
int array[42] = {42};
int *ptr = array;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ToPointer.c).

o compilador reservará um espaço para o *array*. No caso ele sabe que o *array* terá 42 posições para o tipo `int` (que é comum ter 4 bytes, mas depende de plataforma). Esta área da memória está em algum local na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)<sup>*</sup> (que é relativo à posição da variável na função, dentro do [*stack frame*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184498/101)), tem um endereço dela. Então o compilador sabe qual é este local. Ele sabe qual é este endereço. Quando uma operação exige este endereço, o compilador sabe o que colocar ali.

A segunda linha provoca o decaimento de *array* para ponteiro. Então o endereço onde está `array` é colocado em `ptr`.

Lembre-se que estamos falando de memória virtual. O endereço real físico da memória é calculado durante a execução.

---

<sup>*</sup>Em outros casos poderia estar no *heap*, isto é detalhe de implementação também, mas para todos os efeitos é assim.

Answer (score 8):

Na expressão abaixo

```
int *ptr = a;
```

o "valor" de `a` é convertido para um ponteiro para o seu primeiro elemento, internamente pelo compilador. É o mesmo como se tivesse escrito

```
int *ptr = &(a[0]); // ponteiro (para o primeiro elemento)
```

Esta é a regra definida pelo [parágrafo 6.3.2.1p3 do Standard C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3).