# Como funciona o frame-pointer?

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, otimização

Na documentação oficial do GCC existe uma [opção](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fomit-frame-pointer-777) que permite remover o *frame-pointer* quando não for necessário.

- O que o *frame-pointer* faz?
- Como remover este ponteiro pode melhorar a performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não sei o quanto conhece essas coisas mais baixo nível e como a memória funciona. [Isso pode ajudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) se não souber muito.

O *frame pointer*, ou *base pointer* como também é chamado, é uma sub-pilha da pilha onde tem os dados de uma função.

[image: Pilha de chamadas]

O FP é o endereço onde começa a função atual. Ele é usado para voltar facilmente para o local original na chamada assim que a execução dessa função termina, principalmente na ocorrência de uma exceção (*unwinding*). Também é usado como endereço base para o cálculo dos diversos elementos que a função vai alocando, assim o código pode ter endereços relativos.

Há algumas raras situações em que não é necessário manter esse número em um registrador librando-o para outra tarefa. É mais raro ainda ter a necessidade de uso deste registrador para outra coisa, então a otimização é quase inócua ou de raríssima vantagem.

O *debug* costuma usar esse registrador para seu controle. Omití-lo inviabiliza o seu uso, mas aí otimização está descartada mesmo.

Arquiteturas com *frames* de tamanho fixo não precisam disto e arquiteturas que possuem tratamento próprio para o *stack frame* não pode receber esta otimização.

A conclusão é que esta otimização é *quase* desnecessária.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).