# Como a otimização -O3 quebra alguns programas?

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, otimização

Ao compilar meus próprios programas, tenho a liberdade de mudar algumas ***flags*** do compilador e passar a utilizar a otimização **`-O3`**.

Esta otimização consegue quebrar alguns programas. Eu entendo que o compilador deve fazer e assumir várias coisas neste nível de otimização, mas não consigo entender como ela pode quebrar um programa.

[Nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184498/como-funciona-o-frame-pointer) pergunta eu questiono sobre o **`-fomit-frame-pointer`**, e fica claro que ele pode facilmente quebrar o programa em algumas arquiteturas. Meu entendimento para este caso é que o compilador sabe quando deve ativar a ***flag*** ou não.

- Como a otimização **`-O3`** quebra um programa?

**Observação:** Considere para esta pergunta os compiladores `gcc` e `clang`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duas principais causas que podem *quebrar* programas com otimização agressiva (como o `-O3`):

- bugs do compilador
- erros do programador

Os bugs ocorrem porque os desenvolvedores do compilador erram, e o usuário não tem muito o que fazer (e nem cabe a este, exceto mandar um relatório e esperar que o problema seja corrigido). Isso pode acontecer, por exemplo, quando é implementado algum algoritmo de otimização que não considera todos os casos possíveis de saída/entrada.

Já os erros do programador costumam partir de más práticas de programação, são mais comuns e darei um exemplo que já encontrei em códigos reais:

Digamos que você tem uma variável constante:

```cpp
int const a = 5
```

E uma função que recebe um ponteiro `int*`:

```cpp
void f(int* x)
```

Você pode chamar a função passando um ponteiro para `a`:

```cpp
f((int*)a)
```

Agora considere o seguinte trecho de código:

```
int const a = 5;
f((int*)a);
if(a!=5)
{
  //faz alguma coisa
} else
{
  //faz outra coisa
}
```

Parece-me plausível que uma otimização agressiva elimine o ramo do `if`, pois como `a` foi declarado constante, seu valor deveria ser `5`. Acontece que a função `f` pode modificar o valor de `a`, através de seu ponteiro.

Sem otimizações, o compilador emitiria instruções para carregar novamente o valor de `a` e analisar a condição, fazendo o programa funcionar *conforme o esperado*, e a otimização *quebraria o programa*, mas, na verdade, ocorreu aqui um erro do programador ao fazer um cast não seguro de uma variável constante (e alterá-la então resulta em comportamento indefinido, pelo standard).

Os erros de compilador são intermitentes... Em parte criam-se melhores formas de testá-los, diminuindo os bugs, mas em parte os compiladores competem agressivamente por técnicas mais mirabolantes de otimização e, às vezes, novos bugs são introduzidos. Sinto que os compiladores estão ficando mais robustos, e a flag `-O3` (ou equivalente) é segura. (percebo que novas técnicas de otimização em geral são lançadas com uma flag específica, e só depois incorporadas ao `-O3`.)

Numa opinião pessoal: o maior problema é que os programadores ainda usam de técnicas que contam com manipulação direta da memória, truques que saem do escopo da abstração da linguagem, quebrando as premissas sobre as quais o compilador exerce as otimizações.

Answer (score 4):

Alguns compiladores acabam estabelecendo um comportamento específico que eles querem tratar que a linguagem especificou como de comportamento indefinido.

Há uma certa controvérsia. No meu entendimento o compilador pode fazer isto e quebra apenas códigos que preferiram se valer de um comportamento que não é otimizável. A vantagem de existir [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101) é justamente facilitar otimizações.

Passa ser um certo problema se deseja portabilidade um compilador quebrar um código de um jeito e outro quebrar de outro. Muitas vezes precisa criar códigos diferentes para cada implementação ou não ligar esta otimização.

A otimização `O3` é a mais agressiva. Existem outras justamente da escolher se deseja uma que pode modificar o comportamento de forma indesejada. Mesmo os níveis mais baixos podem produzir algum problema no código. Alguns compiladores possuem níveis ou otimizações específicas independentes ainda mais arriscados que `O3`.

Isto ocorre justamente pelo fato porque elas não se atêm a especificação mais estrita da linguagem e se valem de pressupostos específicos.

Comment: +1 contar com comportamento indefinido definido (:p) é a maior fonte de problema. Elaborei uma resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: +1 por responder e mencionar sobre o comportamento indefinido. Optei por escolher a resposta do @Kahler por ter um exemplo e ser mais fácil de entender para iniciantes como eu.

Comment: @jlHertel fez bem.