# Como é um array na memória?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, característica-linguagem, gerenciamento-de-memória

Estou tentando entender os *arrays* da linguagem C em uma máquina de 64 bits (portanto com tamanho de endereçamento de memória de 8 bytes). Ainda não consegui visualizar o que eles são.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(char *arr) {
   printf("%s\n", arr);
}

int main() {
    char c = 'A';
    char *c_ptr = &c;
    char arr[1];

    printf("c\t\t%d\n", c);
    printf("&c\t\t%ld\n\n", (long int)&c);

    printf("c_ptr\t\t%ld\n", (long int)c_ptr);
    printf("&c_ptr\t\t%ld\n\n", (long int)&c_ptr);

    arr[0] = 5;
    printf("arr\t\t%ld\n", (long int)arr);
    printf("&arr\t\t%ld\n", (long int)&arr);
    printf("&(arr[0])\t%ld\n", (long int)&(arr[0]));
    printf("arr[0]\t\t%d\n", arr[0]);
}
```

**Saída:**

```
c           65
&c          140722829046375

c_ptr       140722829046375
&c_ptr      140722829046376

arr         140722829046391
&arr        140722829046391
&(arr[0])   140722829046391
arr[0]      5
```

Estou entendendo que o caractere `c` que vale `65` ("A" em ASCII) fica no endereço de memória com final `75`. Um ponteiro `c_ptr` apontando para esse mesmo endereço (isto é, com esse endereço como conteúdo) fica na posição com final `76`.

O endereço da variável-apontadora na memória e o conteúdo desse endereço são diferentes nesse caso.

Por outro lado, vamos ver o *array* `arr`. A posição inicial do *array* (posição zero) fica no endereço de memória com final `91` e possui o valor `5`.

Um *array* não é exatamente um ponteiro mas se comporta em alguns aspectos como um. A variável `arr` (que pode ser "enxergada" como um "ponteiro") fica no endereço com esse mesmo final `91` e seu conteúdo também é o endereço de final `91`, o que não condiz com o cenário anterior com `c_ptr`.

Mais ainda, essa coincidência conflita com o fato do endereço de final `91` estar guardando o valor `5`.

Qual sentido devo extrair dessas informações? Que tipo de estrutura tenho ali? Sei que a variável em tempo de compilação "desaparece", dando lugar a acesso direto aos endereços.

Tentando visualizar isso na memória, tenho:

```
| ...75 | ...76 | ...77 | ...78 | ...79 | ...80 | ...81 | ...82 | ...83 | ...84 | ...
|    65 | [Oito |bytes g|uardand|o o end|ereço c|om fina|l .... | ..75] |       | ...
       
| ...89 | ...90 | ...91 |
|       |       |     5 |
```

Não sei se está correto. Na verdade fazer essa *ASCII art* me fundiu a cabeça rs. Como devo enxergar a memória com relação a *arrays*, para entender melhor o que acontece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *Array* e memória

[Não existe *array* em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Não na forma que encontra em outras linguagens.

A memória é o grande *array* da computação. A memória deve ser vista como se fosse um *array*, porque para todos efeitos é isso mesmo, é só uma coleção sequencial de bytes.

C acessa a memória, através de ponteiros, portanto o acesso é feito igual um *array* e é só isso que a linguagem sabe fazer, você diz onde desse enorme *array* quer começar acessar e em que posição vai acessar fazendo uma aritmética daquele ponto em diante pulando a quantidade de bytes que você disse que vai usar no tipo do seu *array*, e só, o resto é com você onde parar, e cuidar de todos os detalhes.

## O exemplo

> Estou entendendo que o caractere c que vale 65

Não, a variável `c`, que é do tipo `char`, tem o valor numérico 65, que pode ser representado também como `A`.

Quando você cria um objeto que deve ser um *array* está armazenando esse objeto de forma direta. Não armazena o ponteiro porque isso consegue ser obtido de forma direta, o compilador consegue gerar um código para acessar o conteúdo sem precisar pegar o endereço em tempo de execução em algum lugar diferente do código, ele calcula onde o conteúdo está pela própria pilha de objetos dessa função. O compilador sabe que o conteúdo está em um local tantos bytes depois de onde começa o segmento de memória da chamada dessa função. As variáveis locais de uma função funcionam de forma muito parecida com uma [`struct`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183287/101) (cada membro, que não deixa de ser uma variável, seria uma variável local na função).

De fato o nome da variável desaparece, mas o endereço não, ele fica no próprio código. Note que isso acontece porque é algo local.

O endereço de um *array* é onde o objeto está, não tem um ponteiro armazenado em algum lugar. C convencionou dar o mesmo resultado para pegar o endereço do *array* ou ele diretamente, caso contrário ficaria (mais) confuso.

A tabela mostrando o estado da memória está correta.

## Vendo como o código é em Assembly

Veja [no **Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/dehTY8YqE) como fica em Assembly, sem variáveis (os registradores são as variáveis do Assembly). Tente ler o código, ajuda a entender o que está ocorrendo de fato.

O `mov` é uma atribuição, é só colocar um `=` no lugar da `,` que fica igual linguagem de alto nível. O `lea` também, mas ele pega o endereço em vez do conteúdo, e o que está entre colchetes indica um endereço relativo. A aritmética é negativa porque na prática o a alocação é feita de cima para baixo, ao contrário do que é mais intuitivo para humanos.

RBP é o endereço da chamada desse segmento de memória. Veja mais em [Como funciona o frame-pointer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184498/101), [Estado de registrador em calling covention](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/453732/101) e [O que são registradores e qual é o seu funcionamento básico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320285/101). Note que todos os endereços dos objetos locais são relativos ao início da memória alocada para a função, o tal do RBP indica isso.

Se não existisse o *stack frame* poderia colocar um endereço fixo ali sem usar o RBP. Já existiram linguagem que faziam isso, não sei se ainda rola.

## Conclusão

Então podemos entender que o *array* que está usando (`char arr[1]`) é apenas o mecanismo para armazenar um objeto com uma quantidade de bytes conhecida. Geralmente no *stack frame*, mas tem como ser dentro de outro objeto que pode estar em qualquer lugar. Ele será acessado sempre por um ponteiro, mas a forma como obtém esse endereço pode variar, pode ser calculado pelo código.

Não perguntou, mas pode ficar curioso porque ele desloca 15 bytes em vez de 8 que é o tamanho do ponteiro: [Como funciona o "padding" do C/C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50614/101).

O mais correto quando vai imprimir um endereço é formatar com `%p`.

Uma sugestão é armazenar um *array* dentro de uma `struct` e ver o que acontece. Inclusive ver também como a `struct` acessa a memória.
Pegue o endereço de `argc` e `argv` (os declare, claro) ou faça em outra função que tenha parâmetros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Causaria uma redução na resposta, o que seria uma pena já que está tão bem respondido, mas a dúvida maior era por que `&arr == arr == &arr[0]`(até cogito ajustar o título). C convencionou assim para não causar mais confusão então? O que exatamente ele convencionou, que os dois primeiros devem ser exibidos iguais ao último, que é a posição inicial do "array imaginário"? Sobre não usar `%p`, eu sei, mas queria mostrar o endereço em decimal e o `%p` mostra em hexa. A não ser que exista `%pd` ou coisa parecida :)

Comment: Se for usar decimal deve ser `%u` para endereço de memória, mas é gambi. OS 2 últimos tem um lógica fácil de entender porque de fato `arr` tem como "endereço o primeiro elemento do *array*", que é exatamente o que está escrito no último item da comparação, até porque tem dois operadores sendo usados na expressão, então um manipula para obter um valor e o outro manipular esse valor para obter o valor que já tinha antes. Mas `&arr` é esquisito, como ele é pode igual ao `arr`? Se manipulou uma vez, intuindo, deveria dar outro resultado. Criaram uma convenção que daria o mesmo resultado. É confuso

Comment: Por um momento achei que estava falando das duas comparações de igualdade, na verdade fala do lado direito da última. A comparação de igualdade que fiz não é literal, na verdade deveria ter sido quebrada em duas. O que quis dizer é que pelos valores exibidos na saída as duas comparações valem. Bom, acho que o jeito é aceitar que é confuso mesmo. Minha dúvida é o que foi convencionado exatamente, se foram o valor de variáveis array e o valor exibido por &arr. O último operando da segunda comparação eu entendo que seja simples cálculo mesmo,  aplicação de operadores, não tem nada de convenção.

Answer (score -1):

A convenção em C é que, em geral, o nome de um array é interpretado como um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento do array. Quando você utiliza o nome do array `arr` ou `&arr`, eles referenciam o endereço do primeiro elemento do array, ou seja, a posição inicial. Portanto, todas as três expressões, `&arr`, `arr` e `&arr[0]`, se referem ao mesmo endereço de memória, que é o início do array.

A igualdade entre essas três expressões não é porque o C "convencionou" dessa forma para evitar confusão, mas sim porque faz sentido dentro do modelo de memória do C:

- `arr` é uma abreviação para o endereço do primeiro elemento do array.
- `&arr` é o endereço do array inteiro, que é o mesmo que o endereço do primeiro elemento.
- `&arr[0]` é o endereço do primeiro elemento do array.

Isso é parte do comportamento do C e ajuda a facilitar o acesso a elementos individuais do array. Lembre-se de que um array em C é um bloco contíguo de memória, e o nome do array é uma maneira de acessar o primeiro elemento desse bloco.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Você teria como vincular suas afirmações a documentação C oficial? Com todo respeito mas os conceitos apresentados e escolhas de termos "técnico" parecem equivocados.