# Matriz extensa faz o programa parar de funcionar

Tags: c, array, matriz

Estou com o seguinte problema, quando eu defino uma matriz que seja muito grande, por exemplo: `int matriz[2000][2000]`, compilo e mando rodar, o programa para de funcionar. Testei apenas no Windows e aparece aquela mensagem clássica *"*.exe parou de funcionar"*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int matriz[2000][2000];
    return 0;
}
```

Esse é o código como podem ver eu apenas declaro matriz, e isso já é o suficiente para parar de funcionar na hora da execução. Se eu diminuir o tamanho funciona, eu já testei isso, mas preciso de uma matriz gigantesca mesmo.

Estou usando o *windows 7 profissional*.
*IDE DEV-C++;*
*compilador gcc 4.8.1 32 bits*

Comment: '#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
int matriz[2000][2000]; 
return 0;
 }'

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Você está obtendo um *stack overflow*.

O *array* está sendo alocado da [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) e ele tem limite de tamanho. Objetos grandes devem ser alocados no *heap*, através do `malloc()`. Claro que isto complica um pouco as coisas. Mas é o único jeito. Tem muita coisa que você precisa aprender sobre gerenciamento de memória antes de fazer o que deseja.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define linhas 2000
#define colunas 2000

int main() {
    int * matriz = malloc(linhas * colunas * sizeof(int));
    matriz[0 * linhas + 0] = 0; //coloca um valor na primeira posição da "matriz"
    printf("%d", matriz[0 * linhas + 0]); //claro que neste caso se colocasse apenas 0 funcionaria
    free(matriz);   
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wMl0ls). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kkbnvhbd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/BigMatrix.c).

Leia sobre a [diferença entre *arrays* e ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

Insisto que há muita coisa para aprender sobre gerenciamento de memória antes de sair fazer coisas mais complexas. Se não quiser lidar com esses detalhes, C não é uma linguagem para você.

Aproveita e escolha um IDE melhor.

Comment: Ok, alocamento dinâmico é a parada da vez, ou começar a estudar. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: vou************

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa simples para resolver esse problema é alocar a matriz em tempo de compilação ao invés de alocar em tempo execução na pilha.

```
int main() {
    static int matriz[2000][2000];
    return 0;
}
```

Isso é equivalente a alocar a matriz como uma variável global exceto que a matriz só é visível dentro da `main`.