# Uso de ponteiros

Tags: c, ponteiro, sintaxe

Eu preciso usar ponteiros, mas não estou entendo como expressar a sintaxe, faz parte do objetivo da tarefa (alterar o valor dos parâmetros passados por referência, às funções, tal que estas variáveis sejam impressas na main().

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define MAX 3

 void busca_menor( float *notas, float tam)
{
int i;
float m, valor;
m=notas[0];

for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
{
    if (notas[i]<m)
    {
        m=notas[i];
    }
}
 }

 int main()
{

int i;
float notas[MAX], valor;
printf("Informe a nota de 3 alunos: ");

for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
{
    scanf("%f", &notas[i]);
}

busca_menor(notas, MAX);
printf(" A menor nota foi: ");
printf("%2.f", MAX);
```

}

Comment: Qual é o erro apresentado?

Comment: Ele não retorna o menor valor dentre os informados pelo usuário.

Comment: Você disse que nem compila, então apresenta um erro.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Eu já disse algumas vezes que organizar o código ajuda entender o que está acontecendo. Além de serem difíceis de entender, nomes sem sentido dificultam saber onde se quer chegar. Além disso, o código apresentado nada tem a ver com ponteiros. Está usando *array*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 3
float menor_nota(float valor[MAX]) {
    float menor = valor[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < MAX; i++) if (valor[i] < menor) menor = valor[i];
    return menor;
 }

int main() {
    float notas[MAX];
    printf("Informe a nota dos 30 alunos: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) scanf("%f", &notas[i]);
    printf("\n A menor nota foi: %2.2f", menor_nota(notas));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oLLzGc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mzyryshl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/GeneralExample.c).

Se queria usar ponteiros, deveria fazer isto desde o começo. Até poderia usar ponteiro no parâmetro, mas não faz sentido neste caso. [Se quer usar, pode](http://ideone.com/yaBxBf), não está errado, mas não é adequado neste caso. Ainda assim os erros não estão relacionados com ponteiros, são erros de sintaxe, descuido e de algoritmo.

[Deste jeito faz mais sentido usar ponteiro](https://ideone.com/UoXnuG).

Leia [mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).