# Como alocar um membro de uma struct em C?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, memória

Gostaria de saber se é possível alocar um `atributo` de uma `struct`, segue minha `struct` exemplo:

```
struct MinhaStructExemplo
{
   int * atributo_quantidade; /*Atributo que eu gostaria de alocar na memoria*/
};
```

Para o atributo `atributo_quantidade` eu gostaria de alocar as posições para ele na memória usando o `malloc`, como se fosse um ponteiro, segue o que eu já tentei:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct MinhaStructExemplo
{
    int  * atributo_quantidade; /*Atributo que eu gostaria de alocar na memoria*/
};

int main(void)
{
    int * valor;
    struct MinhaStructExemplo structExemplo;
    valor = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
    structExemplo.atributo_quantidade = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
}
```

Comment: Não estou entendendo. Talvez porque você não saiba como fazer. Neste caso ou você aloca a estrutura ou o membro dela tem que ser um ponteiro. O que quer saber? Não importa onde esteja a estrutura, toda memória necessária para todos os membros será alocada. Só lembrando que os membros que são ponteiros só alocam o espaço para o ponteiro. Para o objeto apontado tem que ser manual.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: E o que você quer fazer que não está dando certo? Quer jogar o que está em valor no membro?

Comment: Eu quero alocar posições na memória para o membro para trabalhar com ele como um vetor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Este exemplo deve esclarecer melhor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct MinhaStructExemplo {
    int *atributo_quantidade;
};

int main(void) {
    int *valor;
    struct MinhaStructExemplo structExemplo;
    valor = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *valor = 10;
    structExemplo.atributo_quantidade = valor;
    printf("%d\n", *structExemplo.atributo_quantidade);
    structExemplo.atributo_quantidade = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *structExemplo.atributo_quantidade = 30;
    printf("%d\n", *structExemplo.atributo_quantidade);
    structExemplo.atributo_quantidade = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
    structExemplo.atributo_quantidade[0] = 1;
    structExemplo.atributo_quantidade[1] = 2;
    structExemplo.atributo_quantidade[2] = 3;
    printf("%d\n", structExemplo.atributo_quantidade[0]);
    printf("%d\n", structExemplo.atributo_quantidade[1]);
    printf("%d\n", structExemplo.atributo_quantidade[2]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OpQppR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hykyhckc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/MemberAllocation.c).

Se deseja guardar o valor da variável `valor`, basta colocar o conteúdo da variável no membro. Ambas são ponteiros. O que é guardado na variável é o ponteiro (criado pelo `malloc()`) e não valor apontado por ele (feito logo em seguida). Então quando queremos apontar para o mesmo lugar, ou seja, para o mesmo valor, basta uma atribuição direta.

Em seguida fiz uma alocação nova na memória e com este novo endereço foi atribuído para o membro da estrutura. Depois um valor foi colocado neste endereço.

Sempre que um tipo for um ponteiro, ele deve conter um endereço de memória que aponte para onde tem um valor. Para obter um endereço de memória existem basicamente três opções: 1) aloca memória com `malloc`; 2) pega um endereço de um objeto com o operador `&`; 3) copia um endereço existente em outra variável (eventualmente pode ser um literal).

Depois o mesmo foi feito com uma alocação sequencial [simulando um *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

Comment: Muito obrigado é isso msm! :)