# Segmentation fault ao acessar conteúdo do ponteiro

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Preciso declarar um vetor de ponteiros, os quais apontarão para tipos `float`, e fazer uma simples leitura de valores.

O programa compila mas após digitar 4 valores obtenho um **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**.

Por que isso ocorre sendo que eu reservei 10 espaços e estou tentando acessá-los?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
float *vet[10];
int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    puts("Digite um valor:");
    scanf("%f", vet[i]);
    printf("%f", *vet[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você precisa alocar a memória pra cada ponteiro. Você criou 10 ponteiros, precisa alocar todos eles... Estou sem tempo pra responder agora. Daqui a pouco alguém aparece pra responder, ;)

Comment: `vet` é um array de 10 ponteiros. Para fazer um array de 10 números usa `float vet[10];` e o endereço de cada elemento no scanf: `if (scanf("%f", &vet[i]) != 1) /* erro */;`.

Comment: @Earendul Quando eu declaro float *vet[10] já não estou fazendo isto? Se não, preciso usar malloc para o que exatamente?

Comment: Isso, como você disse, você apenas declarou. Mas você ainda precisa alocar a memória.

Comment: @DanielaMorais você quer apenas ler 10 números e imprimi-los? Existe algum requisito extra? Existe um motivo para ter usado o ponteiro?

Comment: @bigown Sim, o meu problema é "Crie um vetor com n elementos, sendo que cada posição do vetor corresponderá a um ponteiro para um valor do tipo float. Faça a leitura de n valores e armazene-os na memória."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solução é mais simples do que parece. Pelo que entendi o uso do ponteiro é inadequado neste código. O uso do vetor já é suficiente para resolver o problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float vet[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\nDigite um valor: ");
        scanf("%f", &vet[i]); //preciso passar o endereço do elemento do vetor
        printf("%f", vet[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ds6OTX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fezbzvvy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/DeclareArray.c).

Aproveitei para melhorar algumas coisas e deixar o código mais moderno e dentro do padrão.

É possível mudar este [código para usar ponteiros](http://ideone.com/F1oJyx).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float *vet = malloc(sizeof(float) * 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("\nDigite um valor: ");
        scanf("%f", &vet[i]);
        printf("%f", vet[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xZBNN5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ssrducvg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/DeclareHeap.c).

Aí não precisa do vetor. Note que [ponteiros e vetores são conceitos que podem ser razoavelmente intercambiáveis em certas circunstâncias em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Lendo a pergunta *linkada* aqui dá para entender porque mesmo tendo alocado com ponteiro, pude usar a sintaxe de índice de vetor, que é apenas *syntax sugar* para um cálculo de acesso ao ponteiro. Daria para fazer o cálculo na mão para usar a sintaxe de ponteiro, mas é desnecessário.

A diferença é que [o primeiro código aloca a memória na *stack*, e este com ponteiro aloca no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Comment: Sei que cada posição do vetor funciona como um ponteiro então por isso posso fazer isto? O enunciado parece ambíguo, tanto que declarei um vetor de ponteiros literalmente

Comment: Sim, o enunciado é bem ambíguo, não sei se ele foi proposital ou não. Pelo que li eu iria pela solução do vetor, ela é mais simples, resolve o que foi pedido. Tem que haver um motivo para alocar no *heap*. O enunciado não mostra isto. Quando ele fala em ponteiro depois, ele até está certo porque o acesso ao elemento do vetor, no fundo é feito por um ponteiro. Não faria sentido criar, neste caso, um ponteiro para um vetor. Nada no enunciado indica isto. Obviamente se um dia tiver um problema assim, a solução teria que ser diferente, como já foi dito, falta a alocação dos ponteiros.