# Existe algum modo de eu mudar o intervalo da função rand no meio do código em C?

Tags: c

Olá, eu estava resolvendo uma questão da faculdade sobre um "jogo" em que você deve pensar em um número e a máquina deve tentar acertar seu número. Eu consegui realizar esse trabalho criando uma "fórmula" pra ele achar o valor que o usuário pensa, porém eu gostaria que o programa fosse um pouco mais aleatório, sem necessidade de fórmulas. Então a pergunta é: existe possibilidade de mudança do intervalo de rand no meio do código? Pra cada vez que ele "chutar" um valor, o intervalo diminuir e ele aumentar suas chances de acertar o número.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){

setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
int t, in=0, f=100, cont=1, c;
char a[10];
printf("------------------------------Bem vindo(a) ao jogo de adivinhar um número!!!-----------------------\n\n");
printf("Funciona assim: você deve pensar em um número de 1 a 100 e eu vou tentar adivinhar seu número.\n");
printf("Eu vou dizer meu palpite e você responde se ele é maior ou menor que o número que você está pensando.\n");
printf("Você deve me dizer se eu acertei o número ou se o número que eu disse é maior ou menor que o número que você pensou.\n");
printf("Para vencer, eu devo acertar exatamente o número que você pensou.\n");
printf("Vamos começar? Pense num número para eu adivinhar.\n");
printf("\n\nQuando tiver terminado de pensar, digite 1 para continuar com o jogo: ");
scanf("%i", &c);
if(c==1){
while(1){
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
    t = in+ (rand () % f);
    if(cont==1){
        t=f/2;
    }else if(cont>1 && (f/2)>in){
        t=f/2;
    }printf("Seu número é %i, estou certo?\n", t);
    printf("Se acertei, digite (acertou), se não, digite se seu número é (maior) ou (menor) que meu número: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(a);
    if(strcmp(a, "acertou")==0){
        printf("\n\n\nSou muito bom, não? Já acertei seu número!!\n\n\n");
        break;
    }else if(strcmp(a, "maior")==0){
        f = f + in;
        in = t;
        f = f-in;
        in++;
        printf("\n\nSeu número é maior do que o que eu disse? Ok, vou tentar novamente! \n\n\n");

    }else if(strcmp(a, "menor")==0){
        f = t - in;
        if(f>1){
            f--;
        }printf("\n\nSeu número é menor do que o que eu disse? Ok, vou tentar novamente! \n\n\n");

    }
    cont++;
}
}else{
    printf("\n\nDígito inválido! Da próxima vez digite 1 para continuar com o jogo!\n\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Primeiro, defina "um pouco mais aleatório, sem necessidade de fórmulas". Se deseja que a o intervalo seja aleatório basta não ter intervalo algum O intervalo é justamente para tr um limite. Se quiser só diminuir o limite está diminuindo a aleatoriedade, se quiser aumentar, aumente logo o intervalo e pronto. No extremo do aumento é não ter intervalo. Se quiser insistir nisso, faça o `in` e o `f` serem aleatórios também. É uma bobagem. Fora isto ,só aconselho organizar o código um pouco, definir melhores nomes para as coisas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta primeiramente, e desculpe-me pelas variáveis bagunçadas. No caso o "menos aleatório" seria ele chutar um número literalmente aleatório entre 0 e 100. Na fórmula que eu fiz ele sempre começa do 50, se eu digo que o valor é menor ele vai seguindo uma fórmula, entende? Eu gostaria  de saber se existe meios de deixar isso menos "robótico" e mais na chance mesmo. Claro que não seria puramente chance já que estou diminuindo o intervalo, mas acho que esclareci meu ponto. De qualquer jeito, é uma pergunta de apenas curiosidade. Existe algum modo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muda o `srand()` para fora do ciclo.

Altera a instrução que tem o `rand()` para considerar valores minimos e maximos, usando, por exemplo, `minval` e `maxval` para calcular o numero intermedio (usar `rand()` para achar o numero que o utilizador seleccionou não é eficiente)

```
int minval = 1;
int maxval = 100;

    // dentro do ciclo
    t = (maxval - minval + 1) / 2 + minval;
```

De cada vez que obtens uma resposta `"menor"` ou `"maior"` muda um dos valores

```
    if (strcmp(a, "maior") == 0) {
        minval = t + 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(a, "menor") == 0) {
        maxval = t - 1;
    }
```

Por exemplo para adivinhar o numero 61 a sequencia de variaveis seria assim:

```
                                                         |   novos
minval | maxval |  t | calculo                   | res   | min | max
-------+--------+----+---------------------------+-------+-----+-----
    1  |   100  | 51 | (100 - 1 + 1) / 2 + 1     | maior |  52 | 100
   52  |   100  | 76 | (100 - 52 + 1) / 2 + 52   | menor |  52 |  75
   52  |    75  | 64 | (75 - 52 + 1) / 2 + 52    | menor |  52 |  63
   52  |    63  | 58 | (63 - 52 + 1) / 2 + 52    | maior |  59 |  63
   59  |    63  | 61 | (63 - 59 + 1) / 2 + 59    | acertou
```

Answer (score 1):

O código tem alguns problemas. O principal é usar o operador `==` para comparar *strings*. Em C uma *string* é apenas uma sequência de caracteres e precisa de uma função própria para comparar todos eles e retornar se é maior, menor ou igual. Essa função é a [`strncmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp). Na verdade qualquer linguagem precisa fazer assim, mas algumas escondem isso no operador, mas isso é outro assunto e não vou entrar em detalhes.

Outro problema desse código é tentar retornar uma variável local. Isso não é possível já que o conteúdo no [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) poderá não estar disponível mais. Tem compilador que deixa fazer, o que é ruim já que há grande possibilidade de corrupção de memória. No compilador que eu usei, nem compila.

Então a solução é passar um *buffer* para a função com memória pré alocada. Aí quem precisa do texto aloca como quiser e libera se necessário. Só é necessário se usar o `malloc()`. Em alguns casos é possível usar um [*array* no lugar do ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101) e alocação dinâmica.

Até poderia fazer a alocação dentro da função e retornar esse ponteiro, mas isso costuma ser ruim porque a programador pode esquecer que ele precisa fazer a liberação. Fica uma coisa assimétrica, a função aloca e outra função cuida da liberação.

Eu fiz retornar o próprio *buffer* para que a função possa ser usada como expressão também, mas se isso nunca fosse necessário (pouco provável em código real), poderia retornar nada, já que a passagem do *buffer* é feito por um ponteiro, portanto é uma referência ao real objeto.

Note que eu deixei a função de forma simplificada. Essa função não é segura, nada garante que foi alocado a quantidade de memória suficiente para caber a *substring*. No momento nada impede do final ser menor que o início, o que seria um erro. Seria legal melhorá-la para tratar essas coisas.

Entendo que isso seja um exercício, mas o uso de [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) é mais adequado nesta situação do que fazer uma laço por conta própria.

Tinha um outro problema somando o final e início da *string*. Agora não tem mais, mas se isso ainda estivesse no código, estaria errado, é o oposto, deveria ser uma diferença.

[Evite usar tipo não sinalizado sem necessidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156215/101).

Tem pequenas organizações de código que eu fiz também.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *substring(char *str, char *buf, int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) buf[i] = str[i];
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    char *texto = malloc(6);
    if (strncmp(substring("Hello World", texto, 0, 5), "Hello", 5) == 0) printf("yep");
    free(texto);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RmmdvZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uotwpuqk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Comparison.c).

Em C++ tudo seria diferente porque ele possui um tipo *string* "nativo".