# Uma comparação entre 2 char(s) está errada

Tags: c, string, operadores

Estou manipulando uma cadeia de caracteres com um *loop* `for...` que gera uma nova cadeia de caracteres da mesma, começando e terminando de certa posição (seria `"Hello"` nesse caso).

Quando comparo o retorno da manipulação com outra cadeia de caracteres contendo os mesmos caracteres retorna `false`, com `==`.

Tem uma função para retornar a manipulação:

```
char *substring(char *str, int start, int end)
{
    char sub_r[start + end];
    unsigned int i;

    for(i = start; i != end; i ++)
        sub_r[i] = str[i];

    return sub_r;
}
```

Então, o problema está na condição da declaração do `if`. Deveria chamar a função `printf`. Yep:

```
int main()
{
    if(substring("Hello World", 0, 5) == "Hello")
        printf("yep");

    return 0;
}
```

`substring("Hello World", 0, 5)` retorna `"Hello"`, com o tamanho exato. Também, quando eu tento chamar `printf` com essa cadeia de caracteres aparecem outros símbolos ao invés de "Hello", ou nada.

Algo de errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas. O principal é usar o operador `==` para comparar *strings*. Em C uma *string* é apenas uma sequência de caracteres e precisa de uma função própria para comparar todos eles e retornar se é maior, menor ou igual. Essa função é a [`strncmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp). Na verdade qualquer linguagem precisa fazer assim, mas algumas escondem isso no operador, mas isso é outro assunto e não vou entrar em detalhes.

Outro problema desse código é tentar retornar uma variável local. Isso não é possível já que o conteúdo no [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) poderá não estar disponível mais. Tem compilador que deixa fazer, o que é ruim já que há grande possibilidade de corrupção de memória. No compilador que eu usei, nem compila.

Então a solução é passar um *buffer* para a função com memória pré alocada. Aí quem precisa do texto aloca como quiser e libera se necessário. Só é necessário se usar o `malloc()`. Em alguns casos é possível usar um [*array* no lugar do ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101) e alocação dinâmica.

Até poderia fazer a alocação dentro da função e retornar esse ponteiro, mas isso costuma ser ruim porque a programador pode esquecer que ele precisa fazer a liberação. Fica uma coisa assimétrica, a função aloca e outra função cuida da liberação.

Eu fiz retornar o próprio *buffer* para que a função possa ser usada como expressão também, mas se isso nunca fosse necessário (pouco provável em código real), poderia retornar nada, já que a passagem do *buffer* é feito por um ponteiro, portanto é uma referência ao real objeto.

Note que eu deixei a função de forma simplificada. Essa função não é segura, nada garante que foi alocado a quantidade de memória suficiente para caber a *substring*. No momento nada impede do final ser menor que o início, o que seria um erro. Seria legal melhorá-la para tratar essas coisas.

Entendo que isso seja um exercício, mas o uso de [`memcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) é mais adequado nesta situação do que fazer uma laço por conta própria.

Tinha um outro problema somando o final e início da *string*. Agora não tem mais, mas se isso ainda estivesse no código, estaria errado, é o oposto, deveria ser uma diferença.

[Evite usar tipo não sinalizado sem necessidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156215/101).

Tem pequenas organizações de código que eu fiz também.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *substring(char *str, char *buf, int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        buf[i] = str[i];
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    char *texto = malloc(6);
    if (strncmp(substring("Hello World", texto, 0, 5), "Hello", 5) == 0)
        printf("yep");
    free(texto);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fork/zYCK9Q). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dsihavxx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Comparing.c).

Em C++ tudo seria diferente porque ele possui um tipo *string* "nativo".