# Consultar métodos, classes e atributos na linguagem C

Tags: c, funções, documentação, biblioteca

Eu queria saber se na linguagem C e possível consulta bibliotecas disponíveis suas classes módulos e atributos como na linguagem Python que existe os métodos `dir()` e `help()` eu estou começando a aprender C gora e estou meio perdido. Vou citar um exemplo.

Eu importo a biblioteca `stdio.h` para trabalhar com dados de entrada de entrada e saída mas mas eu não sei os módulos, variáveis, nem classes que a biblioteca possui. Existe algum macete para me ajudar na hora do desenvolvimento?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("C da depressão :\(\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C só possuem funções, constantes, tipos definidos, macros (que até somem antes da linguagem em si ser processada) e variáveis globais (ainda que raro, porque é desaconselhável). Uma forma de achar as informações é olhar os arquivos *header* (`.h`) onde tem as declarações.

Não aconselho tentar aprender dessa forma em nenhuma linguagem. É melhor procurar uma forma mais estruturada, provavelmente um bom livro. É até possível uma pessoa criar seu próprio método de estudo se ela já tiver um bom domínio de programação e ser fortemente autodidata com uma estrutura de comprovada eficácia. Não tente adivinhar o que as coisas fazem, aprenda o que realmente fazem e como usar. Programar não pode ser baseado em achismo, voluntarismo e tentativa e erro. Procure a documentação. Esse é o macete.

- [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/)
- [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/c-run-time-library-reference?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=vs-2019)
- [Man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html)
- [Cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header)
- [Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/)

Só para complementar, já que a pergunta não fala sobre isso, mas a outra resposta é *misleading*: C, como Python, possui tipos para todos os dados. C, ao contrário de Python, possui tipos para todas variáveis. Os tipos disponíveis por padrão em C são: `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`, float, double, `long double`, `_Bool` ou `bool` (disponível em praticamente todos compiladores), `struct`, `union`, *array* e ponteiro.

Existem ainda alguns tipos definidos puramente em biblioteca, entre eles (não todos) `size_t`, `intN_t`, `int_leastN_t`, `int_fastN_t`, `intptr_t`, `intmax_t`, inclusos em `<inttypes.h>` e `<stdint.h>`.

[Ponteiros e *arrays* acabam, de certa forma, se confundindo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

Ponteiros, assim como *arrays*, sempre são usados em composição com outros tipos. Ele serve tanto como referência para um tipo, como para indicação de uma sequência de dados de seu tipo. O ponteiro pode ser composto inclusive com funções. O conceito de *string* só existe mesmo no literal entre aspas e algumas funções em `<string.h>`, no fundo é apenas um ponteiro para `char`.

É possível criar seus próprios tipos, normalmente através de uma `struct` e `typedef`.

Eu entendo o que quis dizer a outra resposta, mas é bom deixar claro que `dict` do Python tem semântica bem diferente de `struct`. Na verdade acho que uma comparação até melhor seria a classe do Python com a estrutura do C. Pelo menos na forma mais simples da classe, se assemelha mais a uma `struct`, ainda que não dê as mesmas garantias. De fato a forma de simular uma classe em C é com `struct`. Simular um `dict` exige algo ainda mais complexo feito por conta própria ou usando uma biblioteca pronta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

A linguagem C não possui **Classes e/ou módulos** como Python, Java, ou C++. O mais próximo disso são as `structs` que se assemelham com as `dict` em python.

Em relação as variáveis, o C possui `int (inteiro)`,`char (caractere)`, `char* (texto)`, `float (ponto flutuante)`, `long int`, e outros.

Além desses tipos de variáveis, tem as `structs` que funcionam bem semelhante a objetos, tanto que em C++, uma `struct` pode representar uma classe com construtores de destruidores.

Os comandos `dir()` e `help()`, só existem em python, pelo menos todas as outras linguagens que trabalhei não possuem essas funções. Em C, tem de se olhar a documentação, ou ver o tipo de valor de entrada e saída dos métodos através das IDEs.

Comment: ficar lendo o arquivo header das bibliotecs e meio chato, e a IDE que eu uso nao e muito boa nesse sentido eu uso CodeBlocks