# Por que a declaração "char *argv[]" funciona no arg principal, mas não no corpo do código?

Tags: c, array, jni

Por que quando utilizo a declaração `char *argv[]` no `int main(int argc,char *argv[])` funciona, mas quando tento utilizá-la dentro do corpo do código com `char *argv[];` ela não funciona?

O erro abaixo é retornado no console ao compilar.

> ```
> error: array size missing in 'argv'
>      char *argv[];
>            ^
> ```

Como eu poderia usá-la dentro do corpo do código?

Comment: Isso realmente tem algo com JNI?

Comment: Sim, estou tentando implementar também dentro do corpo do `jint JNI_OnLoad` @bigown

Comment: Boa sorte em fazer JNI funcionar :D

Comment: vish, assim você corta minha empolgação :D

Comment: Pra coisa simples é fácil.

Comment: Apenas para deixar registrado, era isso que eu pretendia colocar no JNI, [Simple C example of doing an HTTP POST and consuming the response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077802), para ser executado ao carregar a lib, vou pesquisar e quem sabe, com sorte, muita sorte, eu consiga, desistir, jamais. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque precisa, ou dizer o tamanho do *array* para que a alocação seja feita, ou inicializar o conteúdo para que o compilador possa inferir o tamanho.

Funciona no `main()` porque a alocação é feita pelo *runtime* da linguagem com dados vindos do sistema operacional, então a declaração do parâmetro não precisa saber o tamanho, ele só recebe o dado [decaindo para um ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101) que não tem tamanho, não o aloca, por isso não precisa do tamanho.

Funcionaria se tivesse o tamanho, ou se ali fosse ponteiro também.

Answer (score 3):

> Por que a declaração `char *argv[]` funciona no arg principal, mas não no corpo do código?

Porque ([Standard 6.7.6.3p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7)) *a declaração dum parametro como "array de tipo" será ajustada para "ponteiro para tipo"* ... não necessitando da informação sobre o número de elementos.

Ou seja, porque no caso de parametros para funções, `*argv[]` é transformado em `**argv`.

```
int foo(char *arr[]) { /* ... */ }
int bar(char **arr) { /* ... */ }
```

foo() e bar() têm assinaturas completamente iguais.