# Retornar string em C para manipulação fora da função em que foi declarada

Tags: c, string, funções, return

Devo desenvolver uma calculadora que lê strings da forma algébrica da operação com números complexos. Preciso manipular o vetor "principal" fora da função em que foi declarado (recebe). Como proceder? Deve-se usar ponteiros? Como usá-los?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int tam_max = 256;

int recebe(){

    int i = 0;
    int erro = 0;
    char principal[tam_max];
    char real1[tam_max];

    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    fgets(principal, tam_max, stdin);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(principal); i++){

        if (principal[0] == '\n'){
            erro++;
        } else if ( principal[i] == '+' || principal[i] == '-' ||
            principal[i] == '*' || principal[i] == '/' ||
            principal[i] == '=' || principal[i] == '^' ||
            principal[i] == 'i' || principal[i] == 'p' ||
            principal[i] == '0' || principal[i] == '1' ||
            principal[i] == '2' || principal[i] == '3' || 
            principal[i] == '4' || principal[i] == '5' || 
            principal[i] == '6' || principal[i] == '7' ||
            principal[i] == '8' || principal[i] == '9' || principal[i] == '\n'){
            erro == 0;
        } else {
            erro++;
        }
    } 
    return erro;
}

int validaDados(){

    int verifica = 0;
    verifica = recebe();

    if (verifica > 0){
        printf("\nCaracteres invalidos inseridos. Por favor, tente novamente.\n\n");
        validaDados();
    }

    if (verifica == 0){
        divide();
    }
}

int divide(){
    printf("OK ate aqui\n");
}

int main(){

    validaDados();

}
```

Comment: Quer retornar o que? Vai usar esse retorno como? O código não indica o que deseja e não há descrição na pergunta do que deve ser feito. Precisa dar detalhes.

Comment: @bigown Preciso retornar o vetor "principal" para manipulá-lo fora do escopo em que foi declarado (recebe()). Posteriormente esse vetor será modificado dentro de outra função. Minha dificuldade é manipular strings próprias de cada escopo sem declará-las globalmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O correto é sempre alocar a memória necessária onde precisa e passar esse endereço para quem for manipular. Em exercícios a alocação de um *array* no *stack*  não costuma ser problema. [Em aplicações mais complexas pode querer fazer alocação dinâmica no *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

A pergunta não informa claramente como vai usar então vou tentar alguma coisa aqui criando e usando a *string* em `validaDados()` e passo ela como argumento (como é [passado como um ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101) tudo o que for alterado nela será refletida na variável original passada como argumento.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define tam_max 256

int recebe(char principal[tam_max]) {
    int erro = 0;
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    fgets(principal, tam_max, stdin);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(principal); i++) {
        if (principal[0] == '\n') {
            erro++;
        } else if ( principal[i] == '+' || principal[i] == '-' ||
            principal[i] == '*' || principal[i] == '/' ||
            principal[i] == '=' || principal[i] == '^' ||
            principal[i] == 'i' || principal[i] == 'p' ||
            principal[i] == '0' || principal[i] == '1' ||
            principal[i] == '2' || principal[i] == '3' || 
            principal[i] == '4' || principal[i] == '5' || 
            principal[i] == '6' || principal[i] == '7' ||
            principal[i] == '8' || principal[i] == '9' || principal[i] == '\n') {
            erro = 0;
        } else {
            erro++;
        }
    } 
    return erro;
}

void divide() {
    printf("OK ate aqui\n");
}

void validaDados() {
    int verifica = 0;
    char principal[tam_max];
    verifica = recebe(principal);
    printf("%s\n", principal);
    if (verifica > 0) {
        printf("\nCaracteres invalidos inseridos. Por favor, tente novamente.\n\n");
        validaDados();
    }
    if (verifica == 0) {
        divide();
    }
}

int main() {
    validaDados();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XfR8uW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bqlvayyj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ValidData.c).

Arrumei alguns outros problemas. Mas deixei outras coisas que poderiam ficar melhor. N ão sei se o código faz o que deseja, mas está aí a solução pedida na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Seguem algumas opções para o seu caso:

**Opção 1** - O cliente aloca um buffer e passa seu ponteiro como parametro para ser preenchido internamente pela função:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXBUF  (100)

char * obter_msg( char * msg, size_t tam )
{
    strncpy( msg, "Ola Mundo!", tam );
    return msg;
}

int main( void )
{
    char msg[ MAXBUF + 1 ] = {0};
    obter_msg( msg, MAXBUF );
    printf("%s\n", msg );
    return 0;
}

/* OU... */

int main( void )
{
    char * msg = (char*) malloc( (MAXBUF + 1) * sizeof(char) );
    obter_msg( msg, MAXBUF );
    printf("%s\n", msg );
    free(msg);
    return 0;
}
```

**Opção 2** - A função possui um buffer estático interno e sempre retorna seu ponteiro para o cliente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXBUF  (100)


char * obter_msg( void )
{
    static char msg[ MAXBUF + 1 ] = {0};
    strncpy( msg, "Olah Mundo!", MAXBUF );
    return msg;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf("%s\n", obter_msg() );
    return 0;
}
```

**Opção 3** - A função aloca dinamicamente um buffer e retorna seu ponteiro para o cliente (que por sua vez, libera o buffer após o uso):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXBUF  (100)

char * obter_msg( void )
{
    char * msg = (char*) malloc( (MAXBUF + 1) * sizeof(char) );
    strncpy( msg, "Olah Mundo!", MAXBUF );
    return msg;
}

int main( void)
{
    char * msg = obter_msg();
    printf("%s\n", msg );
    free(msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!