# Tamanho de uma String

Tags: c, c++, string

Um `char` na linguagem C ocupa 1 byte na memória.Ex:

```
char ch;//a variável ch esta ocupando 1 byte na memória
```

E um vetor de `char` mais conhecido por `string`, o seu tamanho em bytes será contado de acordo com o numero do vetor. Ex:

```
char ch[4];
```

Essa variável estará ocupando 4 bytes na memoria, ou a contagem é outra?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vamos conceituar corretamente. Variáveis são espaços reservados para armazenar algo. Só isso, nada mais que reservados de alguma forma.

Esta variável reservará 4 bytes na memória. Se a intenção é ter uma *string* padrão do C, então ela poderá ter até 3 caracteres e terá no final um terminador, que é o caractere `0`, também chamado de nulo e comumente representado por `'\0'`.

Nesse caso sabemos o tamanho dela durante o desenvolvimento. E note que nada garante que a *string* estará formada corretamente. Nada garante que ela terá só esses 3 caracteres. O que determina efetivamente o tamanho da *string* é o terminador. Portanto se criar 10 caracteres e depois colocar o nulo final vai funcionar e funções que tratam de *strings* vão considerar que tem 10 caracteres.

Aí pode perguntar como ele coloca 10 caracteres onde estava reservado para 3. Isso é um enorme erro. Mas a linguagem deixa. É problema do programador se virar em fazer certo. Nesse caso o conteúdo irá invadir o espaço de outra variável se produzirá resultado no mínimo estranhos, possivelmente desastrosos e inseguros.

A função normalmente usada para determinar o efetivo tamanho de uma *string* em C, e esse é um dos maiores defeitos da linguagem, é a função [`strlen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) que conta todos caracteres até achar o terminador nulo.

Isso pode ser observado em:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char ch[4];
    strcpy(ch, "abc");
    printf("ch tem %d bytes\n", sizeof(ch));
    printf("ch conta com %d caracteres\n", strlen(ch));
    strcpy(ch, "texto longo");
    printf("ch conta com %d caracteres\n", strlen(ch));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Pc0rtL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wcslhfjm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Size.c).

Note que em C++ geralmente é mais adequado usar o tipo [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Tem algumas desvantagens e várias vantagens. Outra forma só deveria ser usada se houver boa justificativa.

Answer (score 5):

Complementando a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/155935/51124).

---

Você consegue saber quantos bytes cada variável ocupa em memória. Existem duas maneiras de fazer isso, a primeira é simplesmente colocando as palavras reservadas dentro do operador `sizeof()`. A segunda maneira é declarando variáveis e colando ela dentro do operador `sizeof()`.

Primeira:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Char: %d bytes\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("Int: %d bytes\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("Float: %d bytes\n", sizeof(float));
    printf("Double: %d bytes\n", sizeof(double));

    return 0;
}
```

Agora, além de mostrar quantos bytes cada variável ocupa, mostre o endereço dela. Segunda:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main(void)
{
    char caractere;
    int inteiro;
    float Float;
    double Double;

    printf("Caractere: %d bytes \t em %d\n", sizeof(caractere), &caractere);
    printf("Inteiro: %d bytes \t em %d\n", sizeof(inteiro), &inteiro);
    printf("Float: %d bytes \t em %d\n", sizeof(Float), &Float);
    printf("Double: %d bytes \t em %d\n", sizeof(Double), &Double);

    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no Ideone:

- [Primeira](https://ideone.com/tYxTsv)
- [Segunda](https://ideone.com/TaRJD6)

Comment: "Sizeof" é um operador, não uma função. Assumindo uma variável "x", "sizeof x" compila normalmente. Quando é aplicado a um tipo ("sizeof(int)") os parênteses são necessários, provavelmente por razões sintáticas, não por sizeof ser uma função.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: @JoséX., editei a resposta. Obrigada pela observação =)

Answer (score 1):

1. Um array de caracteres ("vetor de char") **não** é conhecido por "string". É um array de caracteres...
2. Este array de caracteres (char ch[4]) ocupa 4 bytes ou 4 posições de memória nos computadores de hoje (eventualmente podem existir ou terem existido computadores onde isso não é verdade, mas hoje em dia isso é mera curiosidade histórica).