# O vetor de char tem um tamanho mínimo?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, memória, alocação, char

Eu to fazendo um trabalho enorme e ele tem dado um *bug* muito estranho ao alocar vetores de `char` com tamanhos específicos. Depois de muita dor de cabeça resolvi fazer um pequeno teste.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
char *c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*3);
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    c[i] = 'a';


cout << c;

return 0;
}
```

Ele imprime: `aa&` (caractere inesperado).

Se faço o teste alocando 2 posições e setando apenas uma, ele imprime: `a*` (caractere inesperado, exemplo).

Por que ele imprime uma posição a mais que o esperado? Se faço o teste alocando 5 posições e setando 4 no laço for com `'a'`, ele imprime: `aaaa` (comportamento esperado). Então não é um problema de alocação, até onde entendo. Pelo meu entendimento o vetor de `char` tem um tamanho mínimo apesar de ser muito estranho. Isso procede?

Comment: Você não está colocando o terminador nulo na string, então o `&` que apareceu nos seus testes é uma sujeira de memória

Comment: Tem mais [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/155935/64969). Também fiz [esta pesquisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+terminador+is%3Aa+user%3A101) para procurar uma resposta com esse conteúdo, procurando do usuário com o maior conhecimento em C/C++ que há na comunidade

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Você caiu em um erro que quase todos programadores caem e a maioria continuará caiando mesmo sabendo disso porque há muita teimosia. Agora você pode aprender o caminho correto de aprender programar. Nunca acredite em testes para te ensinar algo, acredite em documentação e especificação, é ali que mostra como deve ser algo. Especialmente em C ou C++ há muito [comportamento indefinido e não especificado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101) o que faz o resultado não ajudar em nada a definir porque algo está funcionando ou está errado, pode até não ser assim em outro cenário. Além disso é preciso entender todos os detalhes do que está fazendo.

Você sabia que não está programando em C++? Claro, tudo funciona em um compilador C++, mas não é idiomático e não é só frescura optar pelo idioma do C++, ele existe porque ele é melhor que o C, então não deveria usar `malloc()`, a não ser que tenha um justificativa muito forte. O mesmo pode se dizer para usar um *array* de `char` em vez de usar o tipo `string`, onde nada disso estaria acontecendo.

Uma *string* de C, ou seja, um *array* de `char` não tem tamanho então para saber quando ela deve terminar precisa de um caractere terminador, no caso o [nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101), onde está o nulo aí para saber quando parar?

Você está alocando 3 bytes (`char` sempre tem o tamanho de 1 byte então não faz sentido usar `sizeof` nele) e está preenchendo apenas 2 desses espaços, afinal está colocando um caractere na posição 0 e depois na posição 1, quando o contador chega em 2 ele para e portanto nada é colocado ali. O terceiro byte fica lá com o lixo que estiver na memória e sorte sua (ou azar dependendo do ponto de vista porque pode enganar mais parecendo que está certo) se estiver ali um nulo para encerrar a *string*, caso contrário ela encerrará em algum lugar da memória onde achar um byte 0, o que acontecer será coincidência e não o certo.

> Pelo meu entendimento, o vetor de `char` tem um tamanho mínimo

Só você sabe o que isso quer dizer, mas parece que não tem não, não existe esse conceito que você acha que tem na linguagem. Está usando lógica em cima de informação equivocada, então não tem como acertar, a não ser por sorte.