# Checagem de valor nulo automática versus tipos como "Option<T>"?

Tags: null, independente-de-linguagem

Recentemente comecei a aprender Rust e fui introduzido ao tipo [`Option<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), que representa, através de um [tipo de soma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486353/69296), a presença **ou** ausência de um valor (possibilidades mutuamente exclusivas). Essa mesma ideia também está presente em outras linguagens, como `Maybe` no Haskell ou `Optional` no Java.

Paralelamente a isso, algumas linguagens, como TypeScript, C# ou Java, possuem a ideia de **valor nulo** (geralmente representada através de um valor `null`), que *pode*, geralmente, simplesmente assumir valor em um tipo qualquer. Por exemplo, no TypeScript, sem a *flag* `strictNullChecks` ativada, este código é válido:

```ts
//# strictNullChecks desabilitada.

const a: string = 'Luiz';
const b: string = null; // Não dá erro.

console.log(a.toUpperCase());
console.log(b.toUpperCase()); // Erro (em runtime): Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of null
```

<sup>Veja no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhtATgSzAcxgXhgcgBkBXNAL3wG4AoUSWAIyVQ2zzGIBtPKYB6PjAByAY5AwAJgEOYAUxQoQAOmq1wEEJ1lLOITAAo4SqCACqAB3PyAwnAiz9ASkc06GrTr36Gxs5Zt2Ds68AjAAogri%20rIAtjAoxGBQaDGyjki2YGAgsCiycBIw5opWKFAAngQmFqW29vgwIABmMBzcMEA).</sup>

Esse comportamento está associado ao "[erro de um bilhão de dólares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer#History)", de modo que algumas *soluções* foram posteriormente desenvolvidas para o mitigar. Entre elas:

- A criação de tipos de soma como o `Option<T>` do Rust, que indicam, explicitamente, a possibilidade de um valor opcional conter a variação nula.
- O estabelecimento de opções como o [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) do TypeScript ou os [*nullable reference types*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) do C# 8, que, quando propriamente configurados, fazem com que o compilador, verifique, em tempo de compilação, a possibilidade de um valor ser nulo e emitir um erro.

Tendo isso em vista, fico com as seguintes dúvidas:

- Essas duas técnicas de mitigação resolvem o referido problema (geralmente associado a erros como *null reference exception*, *null pointer exception*, *cannot access property ... of undefined/null*, etc). Certo?
- Existe vantagem de uma delas sobre a outra?
- Se houver a possibilidade de escolher entre `Option<T>` e configurações como `strictNullChecks`, quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de cada uma para que eu possa fazer uma escolha sabida?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou começar falando que Java tem e foi a linguagem que cravou mais a ideia do uso indiscriminado de `null`. Agora ela tem outra opção, assim como outras linguagens possuem isso agora de forma oficial ou por bibliotecas de terceiros. Algumas linguagens mais antigas que dependem de legado estão criando modos estritos onde o tipo anulável não é o normal.

O nulo quebra a tipagem estática e forte da linguagem. Uma variável pode ter mais de um tipo de valor, o valor válido e o inválido que na prática é de outro tipo.

As linguagens funcionais não podem ter efeitos colaterais, por isso não podem ter exceções. As linguagens imperativas estão adotando estilo mais funcional (e alguns usuários delas estão abusando disto). A pergunta desconsidera outras formas de tratar a inexistência ou invalidade de um valor, mas isto é importante. Esse mecanismo é mais do que só evitar o nulo.

Então fica complicado dizer que algo não deu certo. A não ser que em vez de retornar um valor simples:

1. retorne mais que um valor com um deles indicando falha, se a linguagem decidir aceitar isso que internamente haverá um encapsulamento em outro tipo, que pode ser considerado mágico;
2. passe um parâmetro por referência que receberá uma informação extra se deu certo, que é convoluto;
3. cria um tipo que tenha o valor se ele for válido ou uma informação de invalidez.

O mesmo vale para um valor dentro de um objeto que pode ser inválido, onde você cria:

1. um campo novo indicando invalidade e um mecanismo que controle no objeto essa invalidade;
2. um tipo que controle a invalidade de seu próprio valor.

Os últimos itens dessas listas são justamente o tipo `Optional` (para alguns contextos pode ser o `Maybe` ou `Result`).

Essa técnica resolve o "erro de um bilhão de dólares" porque o *null* deixa de existir, a linguagem não aceita isso normalmente (algumas podem aceitar opcionalmente, até pelo legado). Na verdade a técnica não é necessária para acabar com o *null*, mas o seu advento e inclusão na linguagem ou biblioteca padrão incentiva um código mais organizado.

Fazendo uma analogia, C usa para representar uma *string* (por padrão) um ponteiro para uma sequência de caracteres mais um dado extra com seu tamanho (sim, isso é o certo a fazer, não se valer do [terminador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155932/101)). As funções padrões antigas de C, trabalham com terminador, mas existem melhores que tem a informação extra do tamanho e isso é mais seguro e correto. Algumas pessoas criam um tipo que as duas informações estão juntas e facilita muito. Em outras linguagens isso fica melhor abstraído. É a mesma coisa, o tipo opcional é o valor que precisa uma informação extra para não ter de enviar junto algo separado e deixar a pessoa ter que lidar com isso. O tipo te obriga fazer o correto e esconde o detalhe de implementação que não te interessa.

Tudo tem vantagem e desvantagem. Eu falo um pouco disto em [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101). Eu gosto mais do tipo opcional do que o nulo ou exceção, ou mesmo um código de erro mais explícito.

- Depende do que está comparando é uma técnica mais universal e padronizada a adotar.
- Em linguagens razoáveis fica mais abstrato e claro o que se pretende, ele tem semântica.
- Te força a fazer o certo e tratar de forma adequada, sem parecer tão mágico assim. Não é uma bomba relógio pronta para explodir como é o `null`, ou exceção que sai do controle.
- Dá mais flexibilidade de como usar.
- Tende a ter mais eficiência (depende do caso e como a implementação de outros mecanismos que estamos comparando).
- Tem mais fundamentação teórica ~~~.

Nem tudo são flores:

- Em alguns casos, ter que lidar com isso em vez de deixar o fluxo normal pode custar um pouco mais caro. Depende um pouco do estilo do código, mas acontece em bem poucos casos. Também pode ter um leve custo extra de memória para guardar o estado, mas depende do caso e da implementação (C# não tem esse custo na maioria dos casos).
- Ser explícito é considerado ruído no código por alguns (em geral pessoas que defendem ser explícito em várias outras coisas, então não considero muito o que essas pessoas falam). Em muitos casos nem tem mais código, pode ter menos, depende um pouco da linguagem (eu entendo que C# não tem um `Optional` oficial porque está esperando o [ADT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486353/101) para fazer direito).
- Algumas pessoas podem ter dificuldade de entender essa forma quando acostumaram com outro jeito.
- Já vi gente falar que pode usar errado, mas todos mecanismos podem e o que vemos na prática é que ele é mais bem usado que seus "concorrentes".

Sim, não são desvantagens de verdade :)

Claro que você não vai usá-lo onde cabe uma exceção corretamente. Onde ele substitui melhor a exceção ela nem deveria ter sido usada. Por isso Rust tem só exceções de pânico, que é onde elas são úteis, e não possuem limitações onde só a exceção resolve. Bem, existem alguns casos, como as [exceções estrangeiras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101), onde **pode** ser melhor do que receber um tipo opcional e ter que lidar com isso, até por eficiência no [caminho feliz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path) que deve ser o comum (nas boas implementações).

Só por compatibilidade e legado deveria optar por nulo.

O ideal é que não tenha uma situação de invalidade ou inexistência do valor, prefira isso, depois vá para o `Optional`, e se ele não existir ou tiver contraindicação específica para o caso, use outro mecanismo.

Claro, algumas linguagens não tem tanto essa cultura e isso conta na hora de decidir o que usar. Lamento por isso.

Note que o tipo `Optional` não é o mesmo que o `Nullable` que não é tão bom porque é um `null` de outra forma.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Ambos resolvem o mesmo problema.

`Option<Tipo> x` é mais explícito, e se parece mais com uma coleção que pode conter 0 ou 1 elementos.

`Tipo? x` é menos verboso, mais ergonômico quando as APIs subjacentes usam muito o idioma objeto-ou-nulo, retornar nulo geralmente sinaliza algum tipo de erro.

Acredito que é por isso que Kotlin e Swift (e talvez C#) adotaram tipos anuláveis, pois as APIs do Android e do iOS usam muito o idioma objeto-ou-nulo, e mudar isso pode levar décadas.

Um argumento contra `Option<Tipo>` é que, se um método aceitava `Tipo` como parâmetro, e passa a exigir `Option<Tipo>`, todos os chamadores desse método terão de sofrer manutenção. Enquanto que, se pedia Tipo e passa a pedir `Tipo?`, os chamadores não precisam mudar.

Outros dizem que isto é uma coisa boa: mudar o tipo de `Tipo` para `Option<Tipo>` muda a semântica do método e portanto é desejável que a compilação "quebre" nos chamadores a fim que sejam revisados. (Pessoalmente, concordo.)

Fonte: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/410724/why-f-rust-and-others-use-option-type-instead-of-nullable-types-like-c-8-or-t