# Função que conta número de elementos vetor

Tags: c, array

Eu tentei usar essa função para contar o numero de elementos do vetor, porém não funciona.

```
int tamanho(int *p) {

    return sizeof(p) / sizeof(int*);
}
```

Eu queria passar no `for`: `i< tamanho(vetor)`.

Já assim funcionou:

```
 for(int i=0; i<sizeof(vetor) / sizeof(int ); i++) {
        //printf("%d", vetor[i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O segundo código no `for` parece ser um "vetor" de fato. E seu tamanho total deve ser conhecido.

O primeiro código na função é apenas um ponteiro. Ele tem seu tamanho conhecido, ou seja, ele é o tamanho do objeto apontado. Ele não entende que aquilo é uma sequência e tem outros elementos e precisa saber o tamanho total alocado para todos eles. Essa informação deve ser controlada pelo programador.

[Há um mito que *arrays* e ponteiros são a mesma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Eles não são, e esse é um dos principais pontos.

A solução é ficar passando o tamanho total da alocação desses ponteiros ou o número de elementos que deve considerar como existentes em todos lugares que precisar. Sem essa informação, não há como saber até onde ir.

O que alguns programadores costumam fazer é criar uma abstração para lidar com isso. Pode ser algo tão simples quanto uma estrutura com o tamanho e o ponteiro para o primeiro elemento, ou um tipo complexo cheio de funcionalidades.

Outra possibilidade é ter um terminador e contar os itens até chegar nele. Que é o que ocorre com *strings*. Mas é lento, não recomendável. *string* é um dos maiores erros de C.

Se aquilo realmente é um *array* e não um ponteiro e tem seu tamanho conhecido e quer apenas encapsular a fórmula `sizeof(vetor) / sizeof(int)` em uma função, há quem crie uma macro para resolver isso, mas é uma solução porca. Seria algo assim:

```
#define tamanho(vetor) (sizeof((vetor)) / sizeof(int))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/GetSize.c).

Mas por favor não faça isso, não compensa. Macros não são higiênicas, se passar algo errado pra isso, vai dar problema, e espere que ele seja sério e perceptível, caso contrário terá um *bug* difícil de achar.