# Por que usamos parênteses em uma declaração de ponteiro?

Tags: c, c++, array, ponteiro, declaração-de-variável

Qual a diferença entre estas duas declarações?

```
int* array1[10];
int (*array2)[10];
```

Por que existem parênteses na segunda?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Podemos ver que ambos são *arrays*.

```
int* array1[10];
```

É um caso onde o *array* terá como elementos dados do tipo "ponteiros para `int`". Então serão armazenados nele endereços de memória. O valor de cada elemento está em outro lugar apontado pelo dado armazenado no *array*.

```
int (*array2)[10];
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/ParenSyntax.c).

Aqui o ponteiro faz parte do *array* e não do tipo dos elementos do *array*. Então temos um ponteiro para o *array* (que [não deixa de ser um ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101), mas isso é outro assunto), portanto a variável `array2` será um endereço de memória que indicará onde o *array* está. Os elementos desse *array* serão do tipo `int`, então o valor já fica dentro do *array*.

C tem um jeito pouco intuitivo de declarar variáveis com tipos compostos. C++ herdou isso. Neste caso os parênteses são construções da linguagem para desambiguar a sintaxe e indicar a real intenção se o ponteiro se refere ao *array* ou ao tipo dos elementos dele. E não deixam de ser operadores.