# Como passar um array como argumento de uma função por cópia?

Tags: c, c++, array, parâmetros

Como [sabemos um *array* é usado como um ponteiro em diversas situações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Um parâmetro que espera um *array* na verdade é um ponteiro, então o que copia é o endereço de memória e não os dados do *array*, é uma passagem da referência.

Mas e se eu quiser passar os dados mesmo? Eu sei o tamanho do *array* e que ele será pequeno, eu tenho certeza que ele será mais eficiente copiando. Como eu faço?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realmente há essa limitação, mas ao mesmo tempo C é uma linguagem muito inteligente e fornece um truque como solução. Alguns dirão que é gambiarra, outros dirão que é uma boa forma de tornar tudo simples e favorecer o uso padrão, dando a chance da exceção ser expressada de uma forma que dá um pouco mais de trabalho e o normal (passar *array* por referência) ser expressado de forma simples.

Mas antes de fazer tenha certeza que o tamanho é adequado. Dependendo de quem estiver dizendo colocará um limite de 4, 8 ou 16 bytes para compensar fazer a cópia. Minha experiência é que 32 ou 64 bytes pode ser interessante, dependendo da arquitetura usada. Mas não torne isso um padrão quando o tamanho permite. A cópia deve ser usada se for a semântica correta para o caso.

A única forma de passar um dado de um tipo não escalar (composto) por valor é quando usa uma estrutura. Por padrão `struct` é copiado e só se usar um ponteiro é que ela se transforma em referência. Então a solução é encapsular o *array* dentro de uma estrutura.

Isso traz algumas vantagens extras já que cria uma abstração e não precisa se preocupar com o tamanho do *array*. Já vi gente usando essa técnica mesmo que depois acabe passando a estrutura por referência, só para não ter que ficar informando o tamanho do *array* em todo lugar do código já que ele tem uma forma canônica do tamanho. Obviamente que qualquer tamanho diferente precisará de uma estrutura diferente.

Alguém pode pensar que isso gera um custo para a aplicação, mas não gera. Não ocupa um byte a mais, nem gasta um ciclo a mais para processar. Claro que existe a diferença de estar copiando o dado e não o ponteiro, isso pode dar alguma diferença e é sua obrigação escolher a mais correta para sua situação.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char array[16];
} Tipo;

void funcao(Tipo p) {
    printf("%zd\n", sizeof(p));
    printf("%s", p.array);
}

int main(void) {
    Tipo dado = { .array = "teste de array" };
    funcao(dado);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/fasUEk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/njtjbptw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ArgumentCopying.c).

Answer (score -1):

Em c++ é só usar std::vector e passar como parâmetro :

```
void foo(vector<int> v) { ... }  // aqui v é copiado
int main () {
  vector x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  foo(x);
}
```

Comment: A pergunta é sobre array.

Comment: Sim, e toda vez q aparece "array" e "C++" junto nas tags, temos q lembrar que o std::vector existe

Comment: Não quando o objetivo é usar um *array*. Eu sempre lembro que tem o `vector` quando o objetivo é usar uma coleção de dados, essa pergunta é especificamente sobre o mecanismo de *array*.

Comment: Normalmente também falo do std::array que é uma implementação padrão desse encapsulamento, mas tem um monte de vantagens   https://ideone.com/KpAJXv