# Por que o índice de arrays e outras sequências começam pelo zero?

Tags: c, array, característica-linguagem, matemática, ciência-da-computação

Por que o *array* não começa com 1? Há algum motivo técnico ter adotado o 0?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tem uma base matemática. Se o primeiro número natural é o zero, por que os computadores deveriam fazer diferente?

Você pode estar pensando: "na matemática matrizes começam pelo 1". Sim, mas isso foge do padrão que a própria matemática estabeleceu em cima de um conceito mais fundamental que começa com zero.

Nada impede uma pessoa começar sua matriz com índice zero, é quase um acaso que na escola aprendemos começar por 1. Claro, é uma convenção universal da matemática, mas que não traz consequências ruins se não for adotado.

Nos computadores pôde-se corrigir isso e tornar o uso mais linear.

Mas há mais um motivo matemático:

> para uma base b, o primeiro `b^N` inteiro não negativo com um expoente N é representado binariamente por N dígitos em todas situações, se começar por 0.

Conforme demonstra uma [publicação no IETF](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/ien/ien137.txt).

Usando base 2 que é o número fundamental da computação: `2^3 = 8`. Então o oitavo número é:

- 8 (binário: 1000) se começar contar do 1, precisa de 4 dígitos para representar o expoente 3
- 7 (binário: 111) se começar contar do 0, precisa de 3 dígitos para representar o expoente 3

Por isso computadores, antes de linguagens, foram construídos assim. Explico.

A memória tem 2^N posições, onde N é o número de bits suportados. Se começasse do 1 para calcular as posições teria que somar 1 para alcançar todas posições, ou fazer N + 1 para poder representar todas posições possíveis, ou ainda deixar o último endereço inacessível. Soluções ruins. Começar pelo 0 resolve essa questão de forma simples e elegante.

Se pensar bem faz todo sentido linguagens serem assim porque os computadores foram construídos começando tudo do 0.

Nem todas as linguagens usam esta forma. Algumas inclusive permitem que em cada sequência determine por qual número quer começar. O que torna fácil criar *bugs* quando algumas sequências com limites diferentes interagem entre si. Essas linguagens costumam ser menos eficientes porque há uma impedância entre ela e o computador.

C foi uma que usou esta forma, e grande parte das linguagens seguem o que C faz, até para facilitar a interoperabilidade com a linguagem franca da computação. C foi criada para ser um *Assembly* portável e mais legível. Tinha que fazer próximo de como o computador funciona.

Começar pelo 0 era importante porque o *array* na verdade é o endereço onde a sequência começa, e os índices são calculados baseando-se nesse endereço (endereço + índice * tamanho do elemento), então `array[0]` é `array + 0`. Se começasse do 1 teria que:

- ou o compilador introduzir uma subtração de 1 no índice para achar o elemento desejado,
- ou deixar um espaço sem dado no primeiro elemento.

Ambas são soluções ruins, ainda mais nos computadores antigos menos potentes. Isso por si só já é um bom motivo para começar pelo 0.

Em C [*arrays* costumam ser apenas ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). E não se sabe o tamanho dele de antemão. Então quando vai varrer o *array*, em geral, não precisa fazer "o tamanho menos 1". Em C faz mais sentido começar do 0.

## Contrariedade

Há um [artigo do Edsger Dijkstra](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF)<sup>*</sup> que questiona o uso do 1. Ele acha que esta opção é um erro.

O Dijkstra fala sobre estética. Ele considera que é "mais bonito" começar pelo 0 e demonstra o porquê. Outras pessoas acham mais bonito começar do 1. Estética é baseada em opiniões.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

---

<sup>*</sup>Sim, um dos maiores computólogos de todos os tempos não usava computadores :)

Esta resposta foi muito baseada em uma [resposta *community wiki* do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13519429/221800).

Comment: * convenhamos que quem tem uma grafia dessa não precisa fazer paper em computador/máquina de escrever

Comment: Zero é natural ou não? Alguns links (em inglês) que explicam que pode ser questão de gosto/assunto mais fácil de explicar com ou sem, ou da ISO 80000-2:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yXeX7ccq9Y&feature=youtu.be&t=250
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283/is-0-a-natural-number
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Comment: Pelo que li no artigo, é o contrário. Dijkstra escreve nesse texto que ele acha que deve começar no 0 sim. O que ele considera feio é começar no 1 por ignorar a existência do 0 e, nas palavras dele, "forçá-lo a ser não-natural".

Comment: @Pretzel você tem razão, não me lembro o que aconteceu na época que fui induzido a erro, obrigado.