# Por que tem de ser colocado o '-1' logo depois de uma variável?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Obs: o código é de um livro que ensina programação

Código:

```
def transação_salva(preço, cartão_de_crédito, descrição):
    arquivo = open("transactions.txt", "a")
    arquivo.write(" %s %16.2f \n %s %16s \n %s %17s \n ------ \n" % ("Preço:", preço, "Cartão de crédito:", cartão_de_crédito, "Produto:", descrição))  
    arquivo.close()
itens = ["DONUT", "LATE", "FILTER", "MUFFIN"]
preços = [1.50, 2.0, 1.80, 1.20]
r = True
while r:
    opção = 1
    for escolha in itens:
    print(str(opção) + ". " + escolha)
    opção = opção + 1
    print(str(opção) + ". Quit")
    escolha = int(input("Escolha uma opção: "))
    if escolha == opção:
        r = False
    else:
        desconto(preços[escolha -1])
        cartão_de_crédito = input("Número do cartão: ")
        transação_salva(preços[escolha -1], cartão_de_crédito, itens[escolha -1])
```

Quero enteder o porquê de (por exemplo) a variável 'escolha' da última linha ter de ser seguida por um '-1'

Comment: Acredito que a indentação do primeiro `for`, dentro do `while`, está incorreta. Pela lógica, `print` e `opcao = opcao+1` estariam dentro do `for`.

Comment: A identação está correta, o programa precisa mostrar números que estão na variável 'opção' que precisa aumentar a cada loop, para que o usuário podessa escolher dentre eles depois. E o 'print' também está correto pois as opções que vão mudar a cada loop são mostradas na tela também. Mas obrigado pela observação.

Comment: Exatamente, eles estão no mesmo nível de indentação, portanto, não estão dentro do `for`.

Comment: É realmente a identação está errada.Obrigado

Comment: **Nota**: a palavra *identação* não existe na língua portuguesa. Ao se referir por recuos de texto, o correto é *indentação*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Na linguagem Python, assim como em muitas outras linguagens de programação, o índice nos vetores inicia em zero. Porém, não é comum você fornecer ao usuário uma lista de opções que inicia em zero, geralmente começa em 1:

```
1 - Opção A
2 - Opção B
3 - Opção C
```

É o que acontece nesse caso. Veja que a variável opção tem valor inicial 1 e é impresso as opções da seguinte forma:

```
1. DONUT           # índice 0 de itens
2. LATE            # índice 1 de itens
3. FILTER          # índice 2 de itens
4. MUFFIN          # índice 3 de itens
```

Percebe que para a escolha X, o respectivo índice é X-1? Esse é o motivo do -1 estar junto à variável `escolha`, dentro do índice da variável `precos`. Se o usuário escolher a opção 1, acessa o índice 0, se opção 2, índice 1, assim por diante.

Pergunta relacionada: [Por que o índice de arrays e outras sequências começam pelo zero?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183798)

#### Terminologia

Por vetor, aplica-se o conceito geral de vetores na programação: uma lista de variáveis de mesmo tipo, acessíveis através de um único nome, diferenciadas por um índice (a grosso modo, para não entrar em muitos detalhes). Isto é, em Python, o vetor mais simples é implementado pelo tipo de dado: `list`:

```
v = ["maçã", "banana", "laranja"]
```

Temos uma lista de `string`, acessadas pelo mesmo nome `v`, diferenciadas pelo índice, número referente a posição: 0, para maçã, 1 para banana e 2 para laranja. Neste ponto que citei anteriormente que a contagem não inicia em 1, mas em 0.

Além, uma `string` por si só pode ser considerada um vetor de caracteres e a indexação funciona exatamente da mesma forma.

**Mas o que são esses índices?**

Vamos imaginar que no nosso sistema operacional, quando definimos um vetor, seus valores sejam armazenados em sequência na memória:

```
|       ...       |  <- Memória continua para cima
+-----------------+
| maçã            |
+-----------------+
| banana          |
+-----------------+
| laranja         |
+-----------------+
|       ...       |  <- Memória continua para baixo
```

Quando criamos a instância do nosso vetor, armazenamos o endereço de memória do início do vetor na variável que o define. Se supormos que nosso vetor começa a ser armazenado no endereço 120, teríamos a seguinte estrutura:

```
|       ...       | 119
+-----------------+
| maçã            | 120
+-----------------+
| banana          | 121
+-----------------+
| laranja         | 122
+-----------------+
|       ...       | 123
```

Ao fazermos:

```
v = ["maçã", "banana", "laranja"]
```

O endereço de memória da variável `v` seria 120, pois é onde inicia o vetor. Para acessar um valor do vetor, o sistema nada mais que adiciona o valor do índice ao endereço inicial. Por exemplo, para acessar o valor `maçã`, que está no índice 0, o sistema acessaria a memória na posição `120+0 = 120`. Para o valor `banana`, que é índice 1, o sistema acessaria `120+1 = 121`. Por fim, para o valor `laranja`, índice 2, o sistema acessaria `120+2 = 122`.

É assim que funciona a indexação dos vetores, explicando o porquê de a numeração não iniciar em 1, mas sim em 0, pois para acessar a primeira posição, o sistema, cedo ou tarde, teria que fazer a subtração em 1 no endereço para obter o início do vetor e seria uma operação a mais para o sistema executar.

Para a `string`, a lógica é a mesma:

```
s = "Stack Overflow"
```

Na memória, ficaria:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| S | t | a | c | k |   | O | v | e | r | f | l | o | w |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  a  a+1 a+2 a+3 a+4 a+5 a+6 a+7 a+8 a+9 ...
```

Se a `string` for armazenada no endereço de memória `a`, o primeiro caractere estará no endereço `a` (`s[0]`), o segundo no endereço `a+1` (`s[1]`), o terceiro em `a+2` (`s[2]`), assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Mal posso ver seus movimentos.

Comment: +1 pelo *link* :D

Comment: Então, tive dificuldade de entender quando você diz "o índice nos vetores inicia em zero", com 'vetores' você se refere a strings ?. E quando você se refere a 'indice' tabém tive dificuldade de entender. Poderia explicar isso por favor.

Comment: Adicionei a parte "Terminologia" na resposta tentando explicar um pouco melhor. Veja se ficou mais claro.

Comment: Ficou bem mais claro agora com a explicação da terminologia... obrigado