# Seleção do primeiro número de uma lista

Tags: python, lista

Olá, estou com um problema que acredito ser relativamente simples em python, porém não consigo resolver ele.
Eu tenho um lista de valores que variam em números positivos e negativos. E eu preciso selecionar dessa lista apenas o primeiro valor positivo de quando ela sobe do negativo. 
Por exemplo:

```
(id) - Valor
 1      -1
 2      -2
 3       1
 4       2
 5      -2
 6      -3 
 7       4
 8       5
```

Se a listagem dos números fosse essa eu precisaria selecionar apenas os valores que estão na posição(id) 3 e 7. Os valores negativos e positivos que estão nas posições subsequentes aos primeiros não servem. Para os valores negativos eu resolvi o problema com a seguinte linha no código:

```
for i in range(len(n)):
    if n[i] > 0:
```

onde i e n são listas que eu criei.

Se alguém tiver alguma dica, eu agradeço.
Obrigado.

Comment: Como o id e o valor se relacionam? Se fosse uma lista simples os índices começariam em 0.

Comment: Se for apenas uma lista você pode usar [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [_slices_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) e [_list comprehensions_](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para conseguir o resultado esperado. Veja [este exemplo](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SandyAustereLinuxpc). Não posto uma resposta pois não sei como é a estrutura de dados que você está usando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, você vai precisar controlar com uma variável auxiliar toda vez que o valor volte a ser negativo.
Veja o código abaixo

```
valores = [-1,-2,1,2,-2,-3,4,5]
aux = 0
for atual in valores:
  if atual < 0:
    aux = 1
  if atual >= 0 and aux == 1:
    print(atual)
    aux = 0
```

A saída deste programa é:

```
1
4
```

Pode testar o código acima neste [link](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/Python-testes)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Realmente a indentação estava errada, deve ter dado algum problema depois que copiei do meu teste no repl.it, obrigado por avisar!

Answer (score 2):

Há três condições que o número precisa satisfazer:

1. Não pode ser o primeiro da lista, pois não haverá negativos antes dele;
2. Deve ser um número positivo;
3. O número imediatamente anterior deve ser negativo;

Então basta verificar essas três condições:

```py
numbers = [-1,-2,1,2,-2,-3,4,5]

for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
  if i > 0 and number > 0 and numbers[i-1] < 0:
    print(i)
```

A função `enumerate` retornará uma tupla com o par chave/valor dos números da lista e assim verificamos se não é o primeiro valor (`i > 0`), se é um valor positivo (`number > 0`) e se o imediatamente anterior é negativo (`numbers[i-1] < 0`).

Vale lembrar que aqui a saída será 2 e 6 pois as listas no Python tem seu índice iniciados em 0.

- [Por que tem de ser colocado o '-1' logo depois de uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184760/5878)

Answer (score 0):

Além das respostas acima (e caso a situação descrita pelo Anderson não seja verdadeira) voce poderia utilizar o módulo *itertools*. Sim, é mais complexo:

```
def pick_first_posivite_after_negative(L):
  ia = iter(L)
  r = []

  while True:
    ia = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x<0, ia)
    tmp = list(itertools.islice(ia,0,1,1))
    if len(tmp) == 0:
      return r
    r.extend(tmp)
    ia = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x>0, ia)
```

#### A ideia

Primeiro jogamos fora todos os elementos em sequência que são negativos (a condição é definida no lambda).

Feito isso, temos duas possibilidades:

```
1- percorremos a lista inteira, composta só de números negativos
2- paramos no primeiro número positivo após uma sequência de negativos
```

Então tentamos pegar o primeiro elemento da lista com o *islice*. Se estivermos no caso #1,  *tmp* será uma lista vazia e a função retorna uma lista de resultados vazia. Se estivermos no caso #2, *tmp* será uma lista de um único elemento, que será adicionado à lista de resultados.

Em seguida, como já temos o primeiro número positivo da sequência, podemos jogar fora toda a sequência positiva (observe que o lambda teve a desigualdade invertida).

Na iteração seguinte do while ou chegamos no final da lista (o dropwhile dos negativos vai retornar a lista como ela está) ou ainda temos uma sequência de negativos.

Caso a primeira sequência de positivos deva ser desconsiderada, o último *dropwhile* deve vir antes do *dropwhile* que descarta os negativos dentro do loop.