# if bugando dentro do for de vetor em C

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, if, for

Meus `ifs` dentro do `for` de vetor estão *bugando* e no final da execução do programa mostrando um número completamente aleatório. Segue o código:

```
//Exercicio_08
#include <conio.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#define max 8 
//Codigo  
main(){  
    int i;  
    int a[max];  
    int par;  
    par = 0;  
    //entrada vetor A     
    for(i=1; i<=max; i++){  
        printf("\nDigite o %i elemento do vetor A: ", i);  
        scanf("%i",& a[i]);  
    }  

    //mostra o vetor A  
    printf("\n");  
    for(i=1; i<=max; i++){    
        printf("%i ", a[i]);  
    }  
    for(i=1; i<=max; i++){  
        if(a[i] % 2 == 0){  
        printf("\nPar: %i", & a[i]);  
        par = par + 1;      
        }  
    }  
printf("\nQuantidade de pares: %i", &par);          
getch();  
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Comment: Tome cuidado pois em c os vetores começam em 0

Observe que de (1 a x sendo x <= 8 )tem o mesmo range que  de  (0 a x sendo x < 8)

Answer (score 4):

Não use `conio`, isto é obsoleto só disponível em compiladores considerados ruins hoje em dia.

Você pode usar [`%d` para lidar com inteiros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) que é mais comum para [não aceitar hexadecimais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152399/101).

O problema principal que impede até de compilar é que está usando O [operador `&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101) no `printf()`. Este operador pega o endereço do dado, e está tentando imprimir o dado, o que dá conflito. Provavelmente achou que deveria fazer o mesmo que no `scanf()`. Lá é diferente. Você não passa o dado para a função, você passa o endereço onde quer que o dado seja armazenado.

Conforme dito pelo Leandro Godoy Rosa, o [*array* deve começar em 0 e ir até o seu tamanho menos 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183798/101). Pode parecer bobagem e funciona em alguns casos indo de 1 à *len*. Mas está pegando coisa que não deve, violando a memória.

Dei uma melhorada no código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max 10

int main(void) {
    int a[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        printf("\nDigite o %i elemento do vetor A: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    int par = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
            printf("\nPar: %d", a[i]);
            par++;  
        }
    }
    printf("\nQuantidade de pares: %d", par);       
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/RFO7ay). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xjxibzuw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/Formating.c).

Comment: Poxa cara obrigado por me ajudar, rodou perfeitamente, aqui quando ele achava numeros pares ele mostrava um numero totalmente aleatorio e eu n achava o erro persistente no codigo uhdsauhda, unico exercicio que me apareceu um erro assim.

Comment: Mais informações sobre essa depreciação: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814975/getch-is-deprecated

Comment: Qual o motivo para usar `%d` em vez de `%i` sendo que os dois tem exatamente o mesmo comportamento?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pronto, você falou.

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa eu já tava meio dormindo, nem era isso q eu ia responder, mas queria cama :D Expliquei porque, na verdade acabei esquecendo de por qual era o erro mesmo, tá aí agora.

Comment: Ok, só uma outra coisa, ao acessar o vetor `a` o índice não deveria ser de `0` até `max - 1`? Você está acessando de `1` até `max`

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa arrumei. Obrigado.