# Objects em Javascript - Obter

Tags: javascript

Olá, comecei agora a aprender JavaScript e queria saber como posso obter a property artist do segundo objecto do myMusic no console.log.

```
var myMusic = [
    {
        "artist": "Billy Joel",
        "title": "Piano Man",
        "release_year": 1973,
        "formats": [
            "CD",
            "8T",
            "LP"
        ],
        "gold": true
    },
    // Add another record
    {
        "artist": "Billie Eilish",
        "title": "Don't Smile At Me",
        "release_year": 2017,
        "formats": [
            "CD",
            "LP",
            "Streaming Services"
        ],
        "gold": false
    }
]
console.log(myMusic);
```

Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Sua variável `myMusic` é um *[array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199751/o-que-%C3%A9-na-verdade-o-array)*, de duas posições, cada posição contém um *objeto*.

---

Para acessar a posição de um array, utilizamos *colchetes* e entre eles o índice desejado, portanto ficaria da seguinte forma para pegar os dados do segundo objeto:

```
console.log(myMusic[1]);
```

Isso porque os [arrays começam em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183798/por-que-o-%C3%ADndice-de-arrays-e-outras-sequ%C3%AAncias-come%C3%A7am-pelo-zero) em *Javascript*.

---

Para acessar as propriedades de um objeto, utilizamos o `.`, isso mesmo o ponto final, então para pegar a propriedade `artist`, temos que acessar o array na segunda posição e então utilizar o ponto para acessar a propriedade:

```
console.log(myMusic[1].artist);
```

Além de utilizar o `.`, também é possível utilizar *colchetes* e o nome da propriedade desejada entre os *colchetes*:

```
console.log(myMusic[1]["artist"]);
```

---

```js
var myMusic = [
    {
        "artist": "Billy Joel",
        "title": "Piano Man",
        "release_year": 1973,
        "formats": [
            "CD",
            "8T",
            "LP"
        ],
        "gold": true
    },
    // Add another record
    {
        "artist": "Billie Eilish",
        "title": "Don't Smile At Me",
        "release_year": 2017,
        "formats": [
            "CD",
            "LP",
            "Streaming Services"
        ],
        "gold": false
    }
];

console.log(myMusic);

//Pegar as informações do primeiro artista
console.log(myMusic[0]);

//Pegar o nome do primeiro artista
console.log("Nome:", myMusic[0].artist);

//Pegar as informações do segundo artista
console.log(myMusic[1]);

//Pegar o nome do segundo artista
console.log("Nome:", myMusic[1].artist);
```

---

Podemos utilizar de laços e iterar no objeto de forma a pegar todos os dados:

```js
var myMusic = [
    {
        "artist": "Billy Joel",
        "title": "Piano Man",
        "release_year": 1973,
        "formats": [
            "CD",
            "8T",
            "LP"
        ],
        "gold": true
    },
    // Add another record
    {
        "artist": "Billie Eilish",
        "title": "Don't Smile At Me",
        "release_year": 2017,
        "formats": [
            "CD",
            "LP",
            "Streaming Services"
        ],
        "gold": false
    }
];

//for no array
for ( const artista of myMusic ) {
  //for nas propriedades do objeto
  for ( const propriedade in artista ) {
    console.log(propriedade, artista[propriedade]);
  }
}
```

---

Você também pode acessar o array com um for simples, pegando o tamanho do array e acessar a propriedade que deseja tanto com `.`, quando utilizando colchetes e o nome da propriedade:

```js
var myMusic = [
    {
        "artist": "Billy Joel",
        "title": "Piano Man",
        "release_year": 1973,
        "formats": [
            "CD",
            "8T",
            "LP"
        ],
        "gold": true
    },
    // Add another record
    {
        "artist": "Billie Eilish",
        "title": "Don't Smile At Me",
        "release_year": 2017,
        "formats": [
            "CD",
            "LP",
            "Streaming Services"
        ],
        "gold": false
    }
];

for ( let i = 0; i < myMusic.length; i++ ){
  console.log( myMusic[i].artist );
  //OU
  console.log( myMusic[i]["artist"] );
}
```

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/JavaScript/Objetos/B%C3%A1sico
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in