# Array é um ponteiro em C?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Eu estou lendo um livro sobre ponteiros em C, mas como sou novo em tal linguagem, ainda pra mim o conceito de ponteiros é um pouco complexo, e ao ler a seguinte definição, me veio a pergunta se um array é um ponteiro.

> **Pointer variables**
>
> The actual size required is not too
> important so long as we have a way of informing the compiler that what we want to store
> is an address.
> Such a variable is called a pointer variable.

Pela definição então, arrays são ponteiros, certo ? Em alguns lugares, se fala que o array ele decai para um ponteiro, seria correto também dizer isto ?

Comment: Eu sei pouco sobre C, mas pelo conhecimento que tenho, os ponteiros não são a própria array, mas sim uma maneira de a identificar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um ponteiro é um tipo especial de variável que armazena endereços.

Se um ponteiro `p` armazena o endereço de uma variável `i`, podemos dizer `p` aponta para `i` ou `p` é o endereço de `i`.  *(Em termos um pouco mais abstratos, diz-se que `p` é uma referência à variável `i`.)*  Se um ponteiro `p` tem valor diferente de *`NULL`* então `*p` é o valor do objeto apontado por `p`.  (Não confunda esse uso de * com o operador de multiplicação!)  Por exemplo, se `i` é uma variável e `p` vale `&i` então dizer `*p` é o mesmo que dizer `i`.

Vamos aos exemplos:

1. `char exemplo[20]`
2. `char *exemplo[20]`

Qual a diferença entre os 2?

No primeiro exemplo tem um *array* com 20 `char`s. No segundo tem um *array* com 20 ponteiro para `char`.

Créditos: [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91336/arrays-s%C3%A3o-ponteiros)

Comment: Muito bom a sua resposta, e também gostei particularmente por você ter colocado os devidos créditos a uma resposta que você pegou como exemplo. + 1 e resposta correta.

Comment: Se eu já tinha respondido não ´era o caso de votar para fechar como duplicata?

Comment: @bigown Não sabia que se encaixava como duplicada. Pensei que por ela ser mais específica, poderia ser considerada diferente.

Comment: @bigown Na outra pergunta o autor pergunta se um array se torna um ponteiro, e qual a diferença entre eles. Na minha eu estou perguntando se um array já é um ponteiro ,e não a diferença entre eles, e não estou perguntando como eles funcionam internamente. Se você ler a minha parte final da pergunta, você verá que não é uma duplicada. Se for assim, até mesmo a que você respondeu na outra pergunta, ela é uma duplicada, pois tem outra pergunta parecida. Isto gera uma avalanche de duplicadas sem fim, a questão aqui é especifica a uma situação, e não em geral.

Comment: @Monteiro Mas a resposta é essa mesmo. Sem saber como funciona internamente não dá pra responder isso adequadamente. Inclusive as duas perguntas usam a mesma frase para perguntar. E resposta do Francisco é só um resumo do que está lá, não acrescenta nada novo. Exatamente estamos tentando evitar uma avalanche de duplicatas sem fim. Como não tem nada novo aqui isso é uma duplicata. A que eu respondi não tem nada igual, tem sobre o mesmo assunto, mas lá na minha tem muitas informações novas.

Comment: @bigown Nisto eu concordo, as perguntas no titulo são as mesmas, e a resposta é baseada na sua. Mas a solução é realmente fechar esta pergunta ?

Comment: Não é só no título, é no corpo também, usa até a mesma frase.A solução é fechar toda pergunta que tem uma resposta adequada em outro lugar do site. E note que nem foi eu que fechei. Inclusive outras pessoas iam votar pra fechar também conforme foi falado no chat.

Answer (score 2):

As variáveis que são ponteiros têm um asterisco em sua declaração. Então o array somente será ponteiro se estiver com aquele asterisco. Samples:

Com ponteiros:

```
int *x;
char *array[];
float *peso;
```

Sem ponteiros:

```
int x;
char array[];
float peso;
```