# Problema com ponteiro e array

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, memória

Eu queria imprimir os locais e valores correspondentes de um *array* utilizando um ponteiro mas quando eu peço para o ponteiro somar o local do vetor com 8 (que é correspondente aos 8 bits de um inteiro) o programa soma com valores que eu nem sei de onde saiu.

Porque no código abaixo o local da variável vetor não não é somado com 8 e atribuído ao ponteiro?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{

int vetor [4] = {1 ,2 ,3 ,4 };
int i;
int *pt;

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){

    pt = vetor + i * 8;

    printf("\nLocal: %d, Valor: %d\n", pt, *pt);

}

}
```

Segue uma das saídas:

```
Local: -1259032880, valor: 1

Local: -1259032848, valor: 4195888

Local: -1259032816, valor: -1259032600

Local: -1259032784, valor: 4195520
```

Saída que teoricamente deveria acontecer:

```
Local: 1259032840, valor: 1

Local: 1259032848, valor: 2

Local: 1259032856, valor: 3

Local: 1259032864, valor: 4
```

E outra dúvida é sobre *arrays* bidimensionais, ou seja, matrizes. A forma de somar uma matriz é a mesma que a de um *array* unidimensional simples? 
Por exemplo:

```
int vetor [4];
```

[1] usa o local inicial e atribui ao ponteiro
[2] soma o local inicial com 8 e atribui ao ponteiro
[3] soma o local inicial com 2 * 8 e atribui ao ponteiro
[4] soma o local inicial com 3 * 8 e atribui ao ponteiro.

```
int matriz [2] [2];
```

[1] [1] usa o local inicial e atribui ao ponteiro
[1] [2] soma o local inicial com 8 e atribui ao ponteiro
[2] [1] soma 8 duas vezes?
[2] [2] soma três vezes?

Ou seja, a hierarquia de local da matriz na memória é que quando termina a alocação do [1] [2], em seguida seja alocado o valor do [2] [1] 8 bits depois do anterior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> que é correspondente aos 8 bits de um inteiro

Um `int` não tem 8 bits, tem no mínimo 16 bits, mas na maioria das implementações e arquiteturas é de 32 bits.

Quando tenta deslocar 8 em um *array* está fazendo 8 bytes e não bits.

A aritmética de ponteiros sempre se dá baseado no tamanho do tipo. Se prestar atenção o segundo ponteiro está deslocado 32 bytes, ou seja 8 vezes os 4 bytes de cada inteiro, o que obviamente acessa um loca indevido já que o *array* tem 32 bytes, portanto o primeiro deslocamento efetivo faz cair fora dele. Não deve multiplicar por 8.

> Porque no código abaixo o local da variável vetor não não é somado com 8 e atribuído ao ponteiro?

Nada é somado por 8 aí. Matemática simples.

> [1] usa o local inicial

Não, o `[0]` é o local inicial.

Como toda a premissa inicial está errada nem adianta tentar entender matriz desta forma.

Leia mais em [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

Answer (score 2):

Tentando complementar a já muito boa e completa resposta do @Maniero, apresento o seu código a mostrar os locais de memoria e valores para cada elemento do array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{

    int vetor [4] = {1,2,3,4 };
    int i;
    int *pt = vetor; //ponteiro começa a apontar para o primeiro elemento do vetor

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {



        printf("\nLocal: %p, Valor: %d\n", pt, *pt);
        //----------------^ Para mostrar o endereço de memoria tem de ser %p
        pt++; //so pode aumentar o ponteiro no fim, depois de utilizar
    }
}
```

Saida:

```
Local: 0x7ffebfbb5eb0, Valor: 1

Local: 0x7ffebfbb5eb4, Valor: 2

Local: 0x7ffebfbb5eb8, Valor: 3

Local: 0x7ffebfbb5ebc, Valor: 4
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/nMJAyM)

Repare que para andar nos vários elementos do array através do ponteiro foi apenas necessário aumentar com `pt++`. Como o compilador sabe que é um ponteiro para `int` então ele avança os bytes necessários de cada vez, correspondendo ao `sizeof` do `int`, que será normalmente `4` mas depende implementação e arquitetura como o @Maneiro já disse.