# Dicionário não retorna todas palavras possíveis

Tags: c, array, string

A ideia do programa é ser um dicionario, o usuário informa a palavra, o programa realiza uma checagem nos caracteres da palavra encontra a posição no vetor e retorna a definição se a palavra constar no dicionário.

O problema é q ele nunca retorna erro de palavra a encontrada, apenas a primeira definição ou a segunda :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h> //lider com variaveis booleans
#define NUM_DEF 7

struct dicionario
{
    char palavra[20];
    char definicao[50];
};

//confere os caracteres das palavras
bool compString(const char palavra1[], const char palavra2[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (palavra1[i] == palavra2[i] && palavra1[i] != '\0' && palavra2[i] != '\0')
    {
        ++i;
    }
    if (palavra1[i] == '\0' && palavra2[i] == '\0')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//busca a palavra no dicionario
int procString(const struct dicionario lingua[], const char procurar[], int numPalavra)
{
    bool compString(const char palavra1[], const char palavra2[]);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < numPalavra)
    {
        if (compString(procurar, lingua[i].palavra))
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            return ++i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int procString(const struct dicionario lingua[], const char procurar[], const int numPalavra);

    char palavra[20] = {'\0'};
    int resultPesq;

    const struct dicionario portu[NUM_DEF] = {
        {"pao", "comida de farinha"},
        {"feijao", "comida brasileira"},
        {"tropeiro", "tipo de feijao"},
        {"queijo", "comida de minas"},
        {"macarrao", "comida de vo"},
        {"mortadela", "comida de carne"},
        {"pizza", "comida da italia"}};

    printf("Digite uma palavra:\n");
    scanf("%s", &palavra);

    resultPesq = procString(portu, palavra, NUM_DEF);

    if (resultPesq != -1)
    {
        printf("%s\n", portu[resultPesq].definicao);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Palavra n encontrada");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a intenção é escrever sua própria função de comparação de *strings* evitando o uso de funções da família `strcmp()`, sugiro que você modifique sua função `compString()` para algo como:

```
bool compString( const char palavra1[], const char palavra2[] )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; ; i++ ) {
        if (palavra1[i] != palavra2[i])
            return false;
        if (palavra1[i] == '\0')
            return true;
    }
}
```

Testando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_DEF 7

struct dicionario {
    char palavra[20];
    char definicao[50];
};

bool compString( const char palavra1[], const char palavra2[] )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; ; i++ ) {
        if (palavra1[i] != palavra2[i])
            return false;
        if (palavra1[i] == '\0')
            return true;
    }
}

int procString( const struct dicionario dic[], int numPalavra, const char procurar[] )
{
    int i =0;

    for(i = 0; i < numPalavra; i++ )
        if(compString( dic[i].palavra, procurar ))
            return i;

    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char palavra[20] = {0};
    int resultPesq;

    const struct dicionario portu[NUM_DEF] =
        {{"pao","comida de farinha"},
        {"feijao","comida brasileira"},
        {"tropeiro","tipo de feijao"},
        {"queijo","comida de minas"},
        {"macarrao","comida de vo"},
        {"mortadela","comida de carne"},
        {"pizza","comida da italia"}};

    printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
    scanf("%s", palavra );

    resultPesq = procString( portu, NUM_DEF, palavra );

    if( resultPesq == -1 ){
        printf("Palavra nao encontrada!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%s\n", portu[resultPesq].definicao );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema principal está na função que compara as palavras, a `procString`:

```
int procString (const struct dicionario lingua[],const char 
procurar[], int numPalavra){ //busca a palavra no dicionario

    bool compString( const char palavra1[],  const char palavra2[]);
    //^---------esta definição é desnecessária

    int i=0;
    while (i<numPalavra){

        if(compString(procurar,lingua[i].palavra)){
            return i;
        }else{
            return ++i;
        }
        //^---- if e else com return

    }
    return -1;
}
```

Sempre que tem um laço com um `return` no `if` e no `else` então o laço só executa uma vez, o que faz com que perca o sentido. Para o tipo de lógica que está a utilizar o `for` costuma ser o mais apropriado.

Ora veja como ficaria corrigindo o problema e trocando por um `for`:

```
int procString (const struct dicionario lingua[],const char procurar[], int numPalavra)  //busca a palavra no dicionario
{
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i < numPalavra; ++i){
        if(compString(procurar,lingua[i].palavra))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

No `main` a leitura da `palavra` também não está certa, aqui:

```
char palavra[20] = {'\0'};
...
scanf("%s",&palavra /*<--aqui*/);
```

`palavra` é na verdade um ponteiro para a primeira letra da string, logo no `scanf` não leva o `&`:

```
scanf("%s",palavra);
```

E se vai ler para `palavra` com um `scanf` torna-se desnecessário colocar `{0}` como valor inicial.

[Veja o exemplo de pesquisa de uma palavra que não existe no Ideone](https://ideone.com/cz11pI)

Nota: não sei se estava a tentar implementar a comparação de palavras como exercicio, mas em `<string.h>` já tem a função [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) que lhe faz isso.

Answer (score 3):

O mair problema aí é que não está comparando as *strings* corretamente. Precisa usar a função [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) para comparar caractere a caractere. Talvez por não conhecê-la o algoritmo ficou confuso fazendo coisas desnecessárias.

O que ele deve fazer é apenas percorrer o *array* de palavras e comparar com a palavras digitada, encontrando retorna  aposição para pegar a definição, se  passar por tudo e não achar retorna -1.

Como há uma definição de constante do número de elementos do *array* talvez possa eliminar um parâmetro da função que passa este número, pelo menos para este caso acho que fica melhor.

Havia outros erros resolvidos, por exemplo no `scanf()`estava passado um ponteiro para um *array*. Um [*array* já é um ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101), então passa o próprio *array*

Tirei tudo o que era desnecessário.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUM_DEF 7

struct dicionario {
    char palavra[20];
    char definicao[50];
};

int procString (const struct dicionario lingua[], const char 
procurar[], int numPalavra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numPalavra; i++) {
        if (strcmp(lingua[i].palavra, procurar) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void) {
    const struct dicionario portu[NUM_DEF] = {
        {"pao","comida de farinha"},
        {"feijao","comida brasileira"},
        {"tropeiro","tipo de feijao"},
        {"queijo","comida de minas"},
        {"macarrao","comida de vo"},
        {"mortadela","comida de carne"},
        {"pizza","comida da italia"}};
    printf("Digite uma palavra:\n");
    char palavra[20] = {'\0'};
    scanf("%s", palavra);
    int resultadoPesquisa = procString(portu, palavra, NUM_DEF);
    if (resultadoPesquisa != -1) {
        printf("%s\n", portu[resultadoPesquisa].definicao);
    } else {
        printf("Palavra n encontrada");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eRCAMs). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yhddssjj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/SearchDictionary.c).