# Percorrer um array usando malloc()

Tags: c, gerenciamento-de-memória, alocação

No decorrer de algumas perguntas aqui no SO vi este exemplo e fiquei com dúvidas.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
clrscr();
int *ptr,*temp;
int i;

ptr = (int *)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
temp = ptr;  

for(i=0;i < 4;i++)
     {
     printf("Enter the Number %d : ",i);
     scanf("%d",ptr);
     ptr++;         
     }

ptr = temp;
   for(i=0;i < 4;i++)
   {
   printf("\nNumber(%d) : %d",i,*ptr);
   ptr++;
   }

getch();
}
```

O que é que realmente está a acontecer neste exemplo?

Porque é que se usa `ptr++` e não `ptr[x]`?

O `malloc()` não aloca sempre memória contínua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O que é que realmente está a acontecer neste exemplo?

Para todos efeitos está acessando um *array*, embora [tecnicamente a definição seja um pouco diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Em C o *array* é sempre acessado através de ponteiros.

> Porque é que se usa ptr++ e não ptr[x]?

Porque quem fez o código quis assim. Ambos funcionam. É comum se usar a notação de ponteiro quando se usa ponteiro e a notação de *array* quando se usa *array*. `ptr[x]` é só açúcar sintático para `*(ptr + x)`. A forma com ponteiro está mudando o local de apontamento por isso precisou criar uma variável temporário para segurar o valor original do início do *array*. geralmente se precisa de de uma variável temporária o ideal seria a notação de *array*.

> É possível usar essa formula ptr[x]?

Não sei o que isso quer dizer.

> O malloc não aloca sempre memória contínua?

Sim, uma coisa não tem nada a ver com outra.

Este código poderia ser escrito assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main() {
    int *ptr = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    int *temp = ptr;  
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         printf("\nEnter the Number %d : ", i);
         scanf("%d", temp++);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) printf("\nNumber(%d) : %d", i, *ptr++);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VuB4y0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lxxlmxte-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MallocExample.c).