# Utilizar ponteiro pode deixar o meu código mais rápido?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Me disseram que se eu trabalhar utilizando ponteiros o programá sera mais rápido. Se em vez de usar índice para percorrer um vetor eu usar o ponteiro, fica melhor?

Comment: Olha, essa sua pergunta não é muito diferente de uma criança de 4 anos perguntando porque o céu é azul. Até é possível dar-se uma resposta que explique refração, difração e interação entre fótons e elétrons de átomos de nitrogênio e oxigênio do ar, mas essa criança não entenderia nada disso. Ponteiros servem para uma infinidade de coisas e podem ou não contribuir com o desempenho, mas para entender uma resposta detalhada dessa pergunta, vai bem longe.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Não, isso não faz sentido até porque o índice de um vetor é um ponteiro. Claro que pode ter alguma situação que você faz errado e pode dar diferença, mas é circunstancial. Veja: [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Em geral fica menos legível usar o ponteiro pode a notação de *array* pode ser usada.