# Por que tipos de variáveis diferentes dão resultados diferentes quando modificadas em uma função?

Tags: c, funções, variáveis, tipagem, parâmetros

Não estou conseguindo entender por qual motivo `x` e `v[0]` são diferentes.

```c
void edit1 (int x) 
{
   x = 9 * x;
}


void edit2 (int v[]) 
{
   v[0] = 9 * v[0];
}


int main () 
{
   int x, v[2];

   x = 678;
   edit1 (x); 
printf (" x: %d\n" , x);

   v[0] = 678;
   edit2 (v); 
printf (" v[0]: %d\n" , v[0]);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em uma das funções o que está passando é um valor que está na [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), na outra está passando um ponteiro que indica onde está um valor que interessa. No primeiro quem é copiado para o parâmetro é o valor que interessa. No segundo o que é copiado para o parâmetro é o ponteiro.

Quando você muda o valor do parâmetro, está mudando só isso, o parâmetro, a variável usada como [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101) nada tem a ver com o parâmetro, e não é afetada, são variáveis diferentes, mesmo que tenha o mesmo nome, o [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) é outro, é pra isso que existem funções, você isola as partes.

Quando o parâmetro é um ponteiro, e entenda que [o *array* é um ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101), acontece o mesmo, se você mudar **o ponteiro** nada é afetado na variável usada como argumento.

Mas o que a sua função faz não é mudar o ponteiro, ela muda um valor que está dentro de um objeto apontado por esse ponteiro.

Quando você cria um ponteiro, e vou repetir, um *array* é só um endereço que aponta para uma posição de memória que possivelmente terá uma sequência de valores, você diz onde estão seus valores, o mais comum não é guardar esses valores em uma variável, mas sim você guarda o ponteiro que diz onde os valores estão guardados. Isto chama-se [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Então quando altera um elemento do *array* está alterando uma posição de memória onde estão os dados do *array*. Nada é copiado nessa parte, só o ponteiro é, você passa ter duas variáveis diferentes em funções diferentes, mesmo que seja do mesmo nome, já expliquei isso, que apontam para um mesmo objeto, uma mesma a sequência de valores. Se você muda um valor nessa sequência, qualquer ponteiro que se referencie para esse objeto enxergará a alteração, porque é o mesmo objeto.

Então nessa aplicação toda você tem os seguintes objetos:

```
`x` de `main()`
`x` de `func1()`
`v` de `main()`
`v` de `func2()`
o objeto que é uma sequência de dados que é apontado por duas variáveis diferentes
```

Nem todos esses objetos existem ao mesmo tempo. O objeto que é a sequência e as variáveis de `main()` existem por toda aplicação por ser a função de entrada então tudo o que é criado ali só será destruído no final da aplicação. As variáveis de outras funções s[ó existem enquanto a função estiver sendo executada, não há a variável antes de executar ou depois que ela já foi executada.

Quando faz `int v[]` é o mesmo que fazer `int *v`.

Código comentado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1(int x) { //o valor do argumento é copiado para x
   printf("endereço de x: %p\n", (void *)&x); //peguei o endereço de x
   x = 9 * x; //mudou o parâmetro e logo em seguida é descartado
   printf("endereço de x: %p\n", (void *)&x); //peguei o endereço de x
}

void func2(int v[]) { //o valor do argumento é copiado para x, no caso é o valor do poneiro
   printf("endereço de v: %p\n", (void *)v); //v já é um endereço
   v[0] = 9 * v[0]; //o valor apontado para o primeiro elemento no objeto é mudado
   printf("endereço de v: %p\n", (void *)v); //v já é um endereço
}

int main () {
   int x = 111, v[2]; //x tem um valor direto na variável x, v tem um ponteiro para outro objeto
   func1(x); //111 é passado para a função, só isso, nada a ver com x
   printf("endereço de x: %p\n", (void *)&x); //peguei o endereço de x
   printf("x: %d\n", x); //x aqui continua sem ser alterado
   printf("endereço de x: %p\n", (void *)&x); //peguei o endereço de x
   printf("endereço de v: %p\n", (void *)v); //v já é um endereço
   v[0] = 111; //colocou um valor lá no objeto criado para ser o array
   printf("endereço de v: %p\n", (void *)v); //v já é um endereço
   func2(v); //o endereço da memória onde foi colocado o objeto array é passado para a função
   printf("endereço de v: %p\n", (void *)v); //v já é um endereço
   printf("v[0]: %d\n", v[0]); //acessando um dos elementos ele foi alterado
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Fjlo8o). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ikqqtmpq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/ExplainValueReference.c).