# Diferença em char* e const char* no inicio de uma função em C

Tags: c, c++

```
const char* lerArquivo(FILE *file, int tam, char *path){
file = fopen(path, "r");
int cont;
char *palavra;
for(cont = 0; cont < tam; cont++){
    fscanf(file, "%c", &palavra[cont]);
    palavra[cont + 1] = '\0';
}
return palavra;
```

Por exemplo neste código e em outros, qual seria a diferença se na declaração da função fosse utilizado apenas `char*` e não `const char*`?

O mesmo vale para outros tipos de declaração, como `int`, `int*`, `const int*`, etc.?

O que muda na função ao utilizar uma declaração diferente?

Comment: Você sabe que o nome const, vem de constante ? Se você diz const no código está basicamente dizendo que o conteúdo da variável não vai mudar. Fora que const ajuda o compilador em alguns casos.

Comment: Que no caso a variável que você vai retornar da função é do tipo const char

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Vou falar inicialmente de C porque é oque usou no código, não usou C++.

É assim que se convencionou considerar o que é uma *string* em C. A linguagem não tem o tipo `string`, ela tem apenas o mecanismo concreto que permite que tenhamos o mesmo resultado.

Uma `string` em outras linguagens não deixa de ser simplesmente uma coleção de caracteres, então é criado um *array* onde cada elemento é um caractere, só isso. Geralmente tem o tamanho do texto em algum lugar (que pode ser o tamanho do *array* - mas alguns casos isso é um pouco mais complicado e precisa de uma informação adicional). Outra forma de definir o tamanho do texto é dizer que um caractere especial indica quando acabou (um nulo é o mais comum), é o caso de C.

Como [C não tem *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101) da maneira como em outras linguagens, então as *strings* são representadas apenas como ponteiros para um `char`, então é o `char *`.

Mas o mais comum é que *strings* sejam imutáveis, ou seja, você não pode mudar o conteúdo dentro dela, é melhor garantir isso dizendo para o compilador que deseja que ninguém mude. Então declaramos que o conteúdo apontado pelo ponteiro seja constante, portanto `const char *`. Nada impede burlar isso, mas dentro da normalidade é respeitado.

Então essa função retorna uma *string* imutável, e espera-se que quem chamar a função guarde isso em uma variável que garanta a imutabilidade também, ou seja, a variável seja do tipo `const char *`. Mas quem chama a função não é obrigado fazer isso, só recomendado, ela pode usar só `char *` e pode mudar o conteúdo do texto.

OS outros tipos tem outros valores que não são caracteres, portanto não formam o que chamamos de *string*, mas o princípio é o mesmo, é, por exemplo, um *array* de inteiros que podem ser mudados ou não (se for `const`).

Em C++11 em diante toda *string* precisa ter `const`. Na verdade em C++ o recomendado é nem fazer isso e usar o tipo [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string).

Note que pode-se mudar o ponteiro e apontar para outro objeto, a constância se refere só ao objeto em questão e não ao ponteiro que é outro valor. É possível fazer o ponteiro ser constante, mas é usado em menos situações:

```
const int * const
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/ConstSyntax.c).