# Confusão no acesso ao tamanho do vetor em bytes em C

Tags: c, array, funções, ponteiro, sizeof

No código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void testaTamanhoVetor(int vetor[])
{
    printf("tamanho do vetor em bytes na funcao: %zu", sizeof(vetor));
}

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    printf("tamanho do vetor em bytes no main: %zu\n", sizeof(a));
    testaTamanhoVetor(a);
    return 0;
}
```

A saída será

```
tamanho do vetor em bytes no main: 40

tamanho do vetor em bytes na funcao: 8
```

Por que os tamanhos são diferentes? Eu só queria acessar o tamanho real do vetor na função.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não passa *arrays* para uma função, só passa ponteiros. A sintaxe é um pouco enganosa parecendo que está usando um *array* mas é um ponteiro. Ali é o mesmo que escrever:

```
void testaTamanhoVetor(int *vetor)
```

E um ponteiro em arquitetura 64 bits tem 8 bytes, portanto é o tamanho que obteve, não o tamanho do vetor. Só a unidade que está sendo compilada naquele momento da declaração do *array* sabe seu tamanho, o programador deve controlar isso por toda aplicação.

Mesmo que faça o abaixo não terá a informação porque são dois objetos completamente diferentes, um deles é um vetor de outros objetos e o outro é um ponteiro para um objeto. Em um você está pegando uma caixa com coisa dentro e em outro você está pegando um envelope com um texto dentro que diz onde tem uma caixa com objetos dentro, obviamente o envelope e a caixa tem tamanhos diferentes.

```
void testaTamanhoVetor(int vetor[10])
```

Você tem que passar o tamanho junto para ter essa informação. Pode fazer isso com um parâmetro extra ou pode criar uma `struct` que mantenha as duas coisas juntas de forma abstrata, que é a forma mais correta, ou pelo menos moderna, para maioria das situações, mas um pouco mais avançada. O mais simples:

```
void testaTamanhoVetor(int vetor[], int tamanho)
```

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

E claro, terá que passar qual é o tamanho partindo de onde o *array* foi criado.

Veja mais em [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

Comment: Como essa linguagem é confusa... Mas entendi, muito obrigado!!

Comment: Não é, e das que tem as regras mais claras, mas as pessoas "aprendem" sem estudá-la primeiro, então fica complicado. E é a mais poderosa e flexível, além de eficiente.