# Por que, em C, um nome de array estaticamente declarada não é um lvalue?

Tags: c, array, struct, característica-linguagem

Por que, em C, [o nome de um array estaticamente declarado não é um *lvalue*](https://diveintosystems.org/book/C1-C_intro/structs.html#_lvalues)?

> Um **lvalue** é uma expressão que pode aparecer do lado esquerdo de uma declaração de atribuição. É uma expressão que representa um local de armazenamento na memória.

Foi dito que é devido a não se poder mudar o endereço-base de um *array* estaticamente declarado em memória.

O endereço-base é a posição de memória inicial de um bloco contíguo alocado/reservado para aquele *array*. No caso de alocação estática, esse bloco fica na *stack* ou na parte *"data"* (dados) da memória do programa, que é responsável por guardar as variáveis globais.

E por que, em oposição a isso, uma struct é um *lvalue*?

Uma `struct` estaticamente declarada também é um bloco contíguo, na *stack* ou na parte de dados, composto pela soma dos espaços alocados para seus componentes, ao qual é dado um nome.

Em que o endereço-base é especial que um *array* não pode ser atribuído e uma `struct` pode?

Por que posso atribuir a uma `struct` estática outra `struct`, mas ao *array* estaticamente declarado dentro dela não posso atribuir outro *array*? Está me faltando alguma noção básica.

Comment: Se arrays declarados estaticamente fossem lvalues haveria dois cenários para implementação: 1) quando o array fosse copiado, o programa copiaria apenas o endereço de memória - do mesmo modo que ponteiros - o problema aqui é que o array perderia sua qualidade estática e deveria ser dinamicamente alocados - do mesmo modo que ponteiros. Imagine, por exemplo, o caso de um array declarado dentro de uma struct. Como a struct poderia reservar memória para esse array, se ele pudesse ser modificado em tempo de execução?

Comment: No segundo caso, o array inteiro seria copiado - nesse cenário, eles seriam mais parecido com structs - mas aqui as dificuldades de implementação só aumentam. Pois como copiar arrays de diferentes tamanhos? Pior do que isso, como C nem sequer conhece o tamanho do array em tempo de execução, o programa nem sequer tem como saber qual é o tamanho do bloco de memória que tem que ser copiado. E essa dificuldade é tão absurda que mesmo a implementação de funções cópia de strings é complicada, haja vista a quantidade de variações de `strcpy` existentes, nenhuma delas muito prática ou boa.

Comment: E por que isso não ocorre com structs? Simples porque structs possuem tamanho fixo bem conhecido em tempo de compilação e execução. Portanto são tão fáceis de serem copiados quanto os tipos primitivos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leia [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101). Isso explica a exceção para este caso. Mudar o valor de um *array* estaticamente declarado violaria a definição de *array*.

Todos os outros casos você tem um endereço direto, então a [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) (que é um *lvalue*) contém um valor. Você pode pegar um valor qualquer e atribuir para algo que já tem um valor (geralmente desde que tenha compatibilidade entre eles, mas essa compatibilidade é flexível).

Conforme já deve ter visto, um *array* acaba sendo um ponteiro para o real valor. Então se você atribuir um valor para ele, está atribuindo para o ponteiro (atualmente apontando para o primeiro elemento do *array*) ou para o valor real? É para o ponteiro, que pela definição da linguagem não é um *lvalue*. Veja a especificação:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.** If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Um ponteiro puro não seria alocado estaticamente, mas ao declarar você disse que ali teria algo estático. Isso não é compatível, a linguagem não pode aceitar.

E você nem poderia sonhar com copiar o valor de um *array* em outro porque nada garante que um objeto seria compatível com outro, e permitirá melar a memória ou deixar sujeira, tanto que todas as cópias de *array* precisam ser feitas manualmente ou através de funções prontas como `memcpy()` ou equivalente, se essa cópia for possível (não pode estar em área protegida de escrita).

Então se *arrays* não decaíssem para ponteiros a atribuição que você queria fazer poderia ocorrer normalmente, porque seria só uma sequência de bytes com tamanho conhecido, assim como é a `struct` (tem exceção) ou outros tipos escalares, sem contar com [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), e por consequência ele seria um *lvalue*. O fato de ser o objeto de forma direta permite que o compilador saiba o que ele está atribuindo.

Isso não é uma característica do *array* em si, mas do endereço da memória, veja que a especificação mostra isso, e podemos exemplificar com algo que também não é válido:

```
int x = 1;
int *y = malloc(sizeof int);
&x = y;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Lvalue.c).

O que está fazendo aí? Está dizendo que `x` que é um nome para um endereço da memória (já leu sobre isso no *link* acima) e que foi colocado o valor inteiro `1`. Depois você está dizendo que essa variável deve apontar para outro lugar da memória que é o que está definido em `y`. Você não está trocando o valor do objeto, mas está trocando a variável. Você não quer e não pode fazer isso, a variável não foi declarada para ser modificada pelo código.

O único motivo que o *array* estaticamente declarado é impedido de fazer o que você propôs é que ele faz exatamente essa operação, mesmo que você não veja por causa do decaimento automático. Ele só "aparenta" ser modificável mas não é.

Você está tentando mudar o ponteiro natural da variável que não foi declarada explicitamente como sendo um ponteiro.

Comment: _"Conforme já deve ter visto um array acaba sendo um ponteiro para o real valor"._ Na verdade não me recordo disso, não sei se li. O que li é que o array (a variável) aponta para o endereço-base ou que na verdade **é** esse endereço-base e talvez tenha lido algo sobre antes desse endereço haver um cabeçalhozinho com alguma coisa, mas posso ter me confundido com algo que o `malloc` faz. Em tempo: os comentários do @VanderSantos não receberam upvotes, estão errados? Parecem corretos para mim.