# Como determinar o espaço alocado por um vetor de char em C?

Tags: c

Seja este espaço (o vetor de chars) definido de maneira estática ou dinâmica (com o uso do calloc ou malloc), gostaria de saber como retornar o valor do espaço alocado por este quando passado para uma função por referência, por exemplo, considerem o seguinte código:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

unsigned long retorna_espaco_alocado_string (char *string)
{
    //return sizeof(string); retornaria 8 bytes pois é o tamanho do ponteiro
    
    /* return sizeof(*string); retornaria 1 byte pois é o tamanho de 1 caractere para onde ele 
    está apontando */

    /* Pensei em criar um laço que conta até que o caractere de parada '\0' seja encontrado, o 
    problema é que também não funciona (até pq ele fica já na primeira posição) */

    /* Pensei também em inicializar esses vetores para que o laço da última opção funcionasse, mas 
    também não funcionou, segue o código de inicialização abaixo */
}

void inicializar (char *string)
{
    int i=0;
    
    while (string[i]!='\0')
        string[i]='a';
}

int main (void)
{
    char nome[30]; //char == 1 byte

    printf
    (
        "sizeof(nome) = %ld\n"
        "function(nome) = %ld\n", 
        sizeof(nome), retorna_espaco_alocado_string(nome)
    );

    //A função retorna não retorna o valor esperado

    return 0;
}
```

Gostaria de saber se já existe algo nativo em C para realizar este tipo de manipulação.

Comment: C não carrega informação de tamanho uma vez que o array _decai_ para ponteiro ao passá-lo como argumento para uma função (já que de fato está se copiando o ponteiro ao primeiro elemento, e é este ponteiro que a função recebe como parâmetro). Obviamente, o ponteiro não saberá mais quantos elementos estarão à sua frente. O que geralmente se faz, nesse sentido, é passar, em outro argumento, o número de elementos que o array, iniciado no ponteiro recebido, possui. Um bom ponto de partida para entender isso é [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/69296)

Comment: Entendi e obrigado pela leitura recomendada. Este exemplo dado é apenas para me ajudar em uma outra questão maior, meu problema principal consiste em desenvolver minhas próprias implementações para strcpy, strcat e etc. Essas funções só recebem como parâmetro 2 strings na maioria das vezes, como elas sabem se há espaço para concatenação ou cópia da outra string sem determinar o espaço alocado por elas antes?

Comment: "*como elas sabem se há espaço*" - elas não sabem, tanto que a própria [documentação](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) diz que as strings devem ter tamanho suficiente. Ou seja, quem usa essas funções tem que garantir isso antes de chamá-las...

Comment: Acho que finalmente entendi. As implementações nativas assumem que o programador está garantindo o espaço necessário, então, executam sua respectiva ação, correto? E é por este motivo que não solicitam como argumento o tamanho das strings.

Comment: Sim, @RicardoFarias, veja este trecho da própria documentação: "_To avoid overflows, the size of the array pointed by destination shall be long enough to contain the same C string as source (including the terminating null character), and should not overlap in memory with source._". Essas funções funcionam sem a necessidade de informar o tamanho porque vão percorrendo a string até encontrar o caractere de terminação (o famigerado _null character_). Vale ressaltar tb q existem variações que pedem o tamanho de modo explícito (e são consideradas _menos inseguras_). Ver, por exemplo, `strncpy`.