# É possível passar um array por valor no parâmetro em uma função?

Tags: c, array, funções, parâmetros

Sabemos que passamos um *array* como um ponteiro no parâmetro de uma função, portanto não é o valor que é copiado, apenas o ponteiro para o local onde estão os dados. Mas e se eu quiser passar por valor porque eu sei que ele é pequeno o suficiente e não haverá outros problemas pela cópia, tem alguma técnica que permita fazer isto?

Não está em discussão se deve copiar ou não, claro que há um custo em fazer isto, é só sobre ter um mecanismo que permita a cópia e se o mecanismo em si tem custo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De fato, o *array* como meio de armazenamento não pode ser passado por valor, [a passagem sempre decai para ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

É possível colocar o *array inline* dentro de uma `struct`. A estrutura é passada por valor sempre que não usar um ponteiro, então tudo o que está dentro dela será copiado de um local para outro. Usando a ideia de que o *array* como meio de armazenamento sempre é por valor, então ali dentro os dados do *array* serão copiados.

Podemos ver no exemplo abaixo que o objeto está em endereços diferentes em cada função, porque foi passado por valor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned int array[2];
} Valor;

void teste(Valor valor) {
    printf("%p, %d", (void *)&valor, valor.array[0]);
}

int main(void) {
    Valor valor;
    valor.array[0] = 10;
    printf("%p, %d", (void *)&valor, valor.array[0]);
    teste(valor);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Lx3jC6). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/ncnaqhfaal-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ArrayByValue.c).

O fato de encapsular em uma estrutura não há custo algum em fazer isso, nem de memória, nem de desempenho em fazer isso. Obviamente que não mais que o custo normal de uma cópia.

No exemplo específico até não terá custo adicional mesmo porque usado adequadamente não pode ficar pior que o ponteiro, e este caso de fato não fica maior que um ponteiro em boa parte das situações (depende de implementação). Além do que acessar dados pelo ponteiro sempre custa mais caro que acessar de forma direta, isso tem que ser considerado no custo. Obviamente que um exemplo com mais dados haverá um custo, se o objetivo for copiar por valor não há custo adicional usar a `struct` ou não.

O mais interessante disso é que ele pode, e deveria, conter também o tamanho do *array*, ficando mais seguro e prático. Quase todas as vezes que vai passar um *array* provavelmente vai passar o tamanho também e assim fica mais abstrato e fácil. Inclusive já vi códigos errados porque foram criar essa abstração quando não queria passar por valor, e passou ter cópia indevida. Se não é para copiar o *array* a estrutura deve ter o tamanho e o ponteiro para o *array*.